# Java 6 NTLM proxy authentication and HTTPS - has anyone got it to work?

Tags: java, proxy, jax-ws, ntlm, squid

I have a Java application (not an applet) that needs to access a web service. Proxies for the web service have been generated with JAX-WS, and seem to work fine. In one scenario it needs to talk through a web proxy server (actually Squid 3.0), which is set to require NTLM authentication.

Running on Sun's JRE 1.6.0_14, everything works fine for accessing HTTP URLs, without requiring any changes: the built-in NTLM authenticator kicks in and it all works seemlessly. If, however, the web service URL is a HTTPS URL, the web service call fails deep inside Sun's code:

```
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: HTTP transport error: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.getOutput(HttpClientTransport.java:121)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:142)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:83)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:105)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:587)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:546)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:531)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:428)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:211)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:124)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:98)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:78)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:107)
        ... our web service call ...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.NTLMAuthentication.setHeaders(NTLMAuthentication.java:175)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.doTunneling(HttpURLConnection.java:1487)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:164)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:896)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:230)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.getOutput(HttpClientTransport.java:109)
        ... 16 more
```

Looking in Sun's bug database turns up a few exceptions in such classes, but all of them seem to have been fixed. Has anyone come across anything like this? Has anyone got this to work?

Comment: Please provide your Imports too?

Answer (score 11):

After some debugging, this seems to be a flaw in the JRE class libraries, specifically in `sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection`.

Studying the HTTP requests and responses in the cases of HTTP and HTTPS endpoints showed that, in the successful HTTP case, the requests had a header `Proxy-Connection=keep-alive`, which was missing on the failing HTTPS case. Reading more generally, there seems to be some confusion on whether one should use "Proxy-Connection" or just "Connection", too ...

Anyway, it is notable that in the HTTP case, the code goes through `HttpURLConnection.writeRequests()`, which contains the following code snippet

```
    /*
     * For HTTP/1.1 the default behavior is to keep connections alive.
     * However, we may be talking to a 1.0 server so we should set
     * keep-alive just in case, except if we have encountered an error
     * or if keep alive is disabled via a system property
     */

    // Try keep-alive only on first attempt
    if (!failedOnce && http.getHttpKeepAliveSet()) {
    if (http.usingProxy) {
        requests.setIfNotSet("Proxy-Connection", "keep-alive");
    } else {
        requests.setIfNotSet("Connection", "keep-alive");
    }
```

There's no such code when creating a tunnel through the proxy for HTTPS, which causes Squid to get upset during the NTLM authentication conversation.

To work around this, in `HttpURLConnection.sendCONNECTRequest()`, I added

```
if (http.getHttpKeepAliveSet()) {
    if (http.usingProxy) {
        requests.setIfNotSet("Proxy-Connection", "keep-alive");
    }
}
```

just before

```
setPreemptiveProxyAuthentication(requests);
http.writeRequests(requests, null);
```

I inject my modified `HttpURLConnection.class` into the JRE using the "-Xbootclasspath/p" flag, and now it works! Not exactly elegant, but there we are.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I found a JDK bug describing exactly the same problem: http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6206466

Strangely, it's marked as duplicate/fixed, although the other bug is quite different.

Comment: Yes, sometimes I'm not sure whether Sun's bug database makes me want to laugh or cry. Possibly they're too busy worrying if Larry Ellison is going to fire them or not to check whether bugs are really duplicates ...

Comment: BigZig could you please provide your Imports too?

Comment: (A few years later...) There is a reference to this very question in a bug report: http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6973030
This is flagged as fixed since Java 7b109.

Answer (score 4):

Are you married to JAX-WS?  I use Apache Axis2, which uses the commons httpclient and has NTLM authentication built-in.

Example:

```
//Configure SOAP HTTP client to authenticate to server using NTLM
HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator auth = new HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator();

//TODO make report server credentials configurable
auth.setUsername("jdoe");
auth.setPassword("strongpass");
auth.setDomain("WINDOWSDOMAIN");
auth.setHost("host.mydomain.com");
auth.setPort(443);

Options o = new Options();
o.setProperty(org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.AUTHENTICATE,auth);
myWebServiceStub._getServiceClient().setOptions(o);
```

Comment: The project is a bit too near release for me to be comfortable with ripping out JAX-WS and replacing it with something, but thanks for the suggestion.