# Browser Authentication using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, functional-testing

I am using following code to pass authorization:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get(http://domainName\\username:password@url);
```

But didn't succeed cause username contains:

```
domainName\username
```

I think the problem is in this? any other ways to pass authorization?

Comment: have you had a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268689/j2se-proxy-authentication)?

Answer (score 1):

You could try URL encoding for same:

```
driver.get(http://domainName%5Cusername:password@url);
```

> //`%5C` is url encode of `\`

Comment: well, now I don't get the error message, but still doesn't work for me, I guess just doesn't work with every site