# How do I make HttpURLConnection use a proxy?

Tags: java, windows, http, proxy

If I do this...

```
conn = new URL(urlString).openConnection();
System.out.println("Proxy? " + conn.usingProxy());
```

it prints

```
Proxy? false
```

The problem is, I am behind a proxy. Where does the JVM get its proxy information from on Windows? How do I set this up? All my other apps seem perfectly happy with my proxy.

Answer (score 382, accepted):

Since java 1.5 you can also pass a [java.net.Proxy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/Proxy.html) instance to the [`openConnection(proxy)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openConnection%28java.net.Proxy%29) method:

```
//Proxy instance, proxy ip = 10.0.0.1 with port 8080
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("10.0.0.1", 8080));
conn = new URL(urlString).openConnection(proxy);
```

If your proxy requires authentication it will give you response 407.

In this case you'll need the following code:

```
    Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator() {

        public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return (new PasswordAuthentication("user",
                    "password".toCharArray()));
        }
    };
    Authenticator.setDefault(authenticator);
```

Comment: can we provide proxy username and proxy password through it.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking. And yet I accidentally clicked downvote while copy/pasting, only to notice too late to undo it. Sorry.

Comment: What if you have different username/password pairs for the different proxies? Calling a static method to set the default Authenticator isn't ideal, this is not much better than setting the sys properties method..

Comment: I'm trying to use this to check connection with google.com but `getResponseCode()` returns `recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)` exception. ¿what would be wrong?

Comment: Do we have to call Authenticator every time we open a HttpURLConnection? Or set this only once?

Comment: Authenticator.default is a static (i.e. global) variable, so it's only once.
But please note that the Authenticator above is just a minimal example. It can only handle one password at a time. Google for examples that can handle multiple hosts with different passwords.

Comment: Since 8u11 this will not work by default with Basic authentication, http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u111-relnotes-3124969.html

jdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes system property must be set to emtpty

Comment: In case you have domain. Do as following: `new PasswordAuthentication("domainName\\user", "password".toCharArray());`

Comment: @NickDK, Your answer is very good and easy to understand, I was looking for the same piece of code, but I am getting " java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out " while establishing the connecting. Can someone please guide me

Comment: for multiple proxies, instead of using an Authenticator like in the example, just setting the 'Proxy-Authorization' header is enough, but may not always fit your requirements, for details see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Proxy-Authorization

Comment: @Chris, I would like to clarify your statement: "just setting the 'Proxy-Authorization'" & , "but may not always fit your requirements". If proxy requires NTLM authentication other than Basic authentication, setting 'Proxy-Authorization' will not be as simple as in case of Basic auth.

Comment: The `Authenticator` part resolved the issue for me using the okhttp3 library as well using a SOCKS5 proxy.

Comment: How to read cookie from target and write to response for user browser?

Answer (score 39):

This is fairly easy to answer from the internet. Set system properties `http.proxyHost` and `http.proxyPort`. You can do this with `System.setProperty()`, or from the command line with the `-D` syntax. EDIT: per comment, set `https.proxyPort` and `https.proxyHost` for HTTPS.

Comment: Please edit your answer to include for the scenario when it's https. If you connect to a https endpoint you have to use **https.proxyHost** and **https.proxyPort**.

Comment: Although your answer seems to be correct, it lacks details. Please add some code examples as to how to use these properties.

Answer (score 23):

Proxies are supported through two system properties: http.proxyHost and http.proxyPort. They must be set to the proxy server and port respectively. The following basic example illustrates it:

```
String url = "http://www.google.com/",
       proxy = "proxy.mydomain.com",
       port = "8080";
URL server = new URL(url);
Properties systemProperties = System.getProperties();
systemProperties.setProperty("http.proxyHost",proxy);
systemProperties.setProperty("http.proxyPort",port);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)server.openConnection();
connection.connect();
InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
readResponse(in);
```

Comment: @Pascal Do you happen to know what are the major differences of using latest Java approach in comparison to Apache `commons-httpclient`? As Java supports proxying and authentication (as you mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626549/authenticated-http-proxy-with-java), for simple cases (like retrieve one file from public HTTP server) there is no reason to use Apache library. What is your recommendation?

Comment: @dma_k I agree with you, for simple use cases like the one you described I wouldn't use a third party library.

Comment: Do you know how to support the nonProxyHosts? I see that my device support it but doesn't know how to make my app handle it.

Comment: But variable `systemProperties` is not used by the `connection`!

Comment: How to pass read cookie ???

Answer (score 19):

You can also set

```
-Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true
```

On Windows and Linux this will use the system settings so you don't need to repeat yourself (DRY)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html#Proxies

Comment: This works only with manual proxy server configuration. Automatic proxy configuration and proxies configured through script are not (yet) propagated to "useSystemProxies".

Comment: This worked for me when setting the proxyHost and proxyPort didn't. Thanks!

Comment: Likewise, this worked from behind my company proxy when calls to `System.setProperty` for the `https.proxyHost` and `https.proxyPort` for some reason weren't cutting the mustard.

Answer (score 10):

Set following before you openConnection,

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "host");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "port_number");
```

If proxy requires authentication,

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyUser", "user");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPassword", "password");
```

Comment: I actually think "http.proxyUser" and "http.proxyPassword" are not supported anymore.

See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120797/how-do-i-set-the-proxy-to-be-used-by-the-jvm for more details.

Answer (score 6):

For Java 1.8 and higher you must set `-Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=` to make proxies with Basic Authorization working with https.

Comment: Background information about this is discussed at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41806422/java-web-start-unable-to-tunnel-through-proxy-since-java-8-update-111

Answer (score 4):

The approved answer will work ... if you know your proxy host and port =) . But in case you are looking for the proxy host and port the steps below should help

> if auto configured proxy is given: then
>
> 1> open IE(or any browser)
>
> 2> get the url address from your browser through IE->Tools->internet
>   option->connections->LAN Settings-> get address and give in url eg: as
>   http://autocache.abc.com/ and enter, a file will be downloaded with
>   .pac format, save to desktop
>
> 3> open .pac file in textpad, identify PROXY:
>
> In your editor, it will come something like:
>
> return "PROXY web-proxy.ind.abc.com:8080; PROXY
>   proxy.sgp.abc.com:8080";

kudos to bekur from [maven in 5 min not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5704010/maven-in-5-min-not-working)

Once you have the host and port just pop in into this and your good to go

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("web-proxy.ind.abc.com", 8080));
        URLConnection connection = new URL(url).openConnection(proxy);
```