# Get android proxy crendetials

Tags: android, proxy, credentials, http-get

I have configured a proxy on my Android device. I'm developing an aplication in which I need to make a HTTP get throught the proxy. I can make the HTTP get but I MUST set again the user and password into the httpclient, so, how I can get the proxy credentials stored in the android device?

thanks.

Comment: What device and OS version are you using?

Comment: Samsung galaxy tab 10.1. Android 3.1

Answer (score 0):

I think that this could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1626616/355465

Answer (score 0):

cntlm is free local proxy (http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/) and can be used as a middle-ware  between your device and the proxy with user name  , it has option with cntlm -H to store your password , so you do not need to change your code, just configure the device to use cntlm proxy