# Netbeans not able to connect to internet

Tags: java, windows-8, netbeans-7

I am using windows 8 (64bit) but not able to get access to internet using netbeans. When I am trying to update via Help > Check for Update I am getting

```
Check your network connection, verify that your proxy settings are configured correctly in the NetBeans IDE, or try again later.
```

When I am trying to access some url with a program in java I am getting error

```
connection refused: Address is invalid on local machine
```

whats going on here????

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I need to force Java to use IPv4, to do so set it by command

```
setx _JAVA_OPTIONS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

Comment: setx: command not found
Is this a command at the bash? Where do you enter this?

Comment: are u on windows 8? For me setx is a valid command, otherwise check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16139520/what-is-the-location-of-the-setx-command-in-windows-7

Comment: thanks (it has been a wrong proxy setting in the first place)

Comment: I am on Linux (Ubuntu 14.04)

Answer (score 0):

Are you behind a proxy server? Go to Tools > Options > General and try to change the network settings according to your network config.
EDIT: It may also be a firewall issue.

Comment: No, I am not behind the firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a proxy server, because if you are then you will need to use a ProxyAuthenticator java class which will can be called within your Java class. This should allow your class to access the Internet.

However, it may be worth checking your NetBeans Internet settings (Tools -> Options -> General) and checking whether a HTTP Proxy authentication is being used. Even so, a ProxyAuthenticator Java class may still be required (assuming a Proxy server is being used). Please see [Authenticated HTTP proxy with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626549/authenticated-http-proxy-with-java)