# What is the location of the setx command in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, environment-variables

I accidentally deleted my Path variable in Windows. But I have a copy of it saved in a text file. I cannot modify the Path variable from Start->Computer->Properties->Advanced System Settings->Environment Variables, etc. because Windows cannot find systempropertiesadvanced.exe (since the path is empty). So I want to set the path using the setx command from cmd.exe. But I get the error that setx is not a recognized command (probably because the path is empty). So where is the setx command located in Windows 7, usually? Also, if I am missing something here in my reasoning, please let me know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is in `C:\Windows\System32` (on 64-bit Win7) which is the same location as SystemPropertiesAdvanced.exe.

Comment: Perfect. I instead just ran SystemPropertiesAdvanced.exe and set the path from there.