# How to setup Django using command prompt

Tags: python, django, windows, python-3.x, command-line

I have installed python correctly but I cannot figure out how to set the path using command prompt... I am confused is it the command prompt or the python shell which we have to use as the documentation states. This is the command but its not working

C:\Python34\;C:\Python34\Scripts;

As written in the documentation here: [Docs Link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/windows/)

I am using windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it by using the control panel>system and security>system>advanced system settings. There is an option of adding environment variable, and added C:\Python34\;C:\Python34\Scripts; in the new option

Answer (score 0):

That's not a command at all, and the documentation says quite clearly that it is what you need to add to the PATH environment variable.

Comment: hey i m new to it so i dont know it at all u dont have to down vote it. Instead try to clarify it...

Answer (score 0):

In Vista, Windows 7 and Windows 8 we can set path from command line  using ‘setx’ command.

```
setx path "%path%;c:\directoryPath"
```

For example, to add c:\dir1\dir2 to the path variable, we can run the below command.

```
setx path "%path%;c:\dir1\dir2"
```

Comment: setx path "%path%;c:\Python34\Scripts" this is what i added its giving an error that setx is not recgonized

Comment: may be you need this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16139520/what-is-the-location-of-the-setx-command-in-windows-7

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
if "C:\\Python34" not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append("C:\\Python34")

print (sys.path)
```

This would work if you want to add python path using python script. But it would not be stable so it would be better if you manually add python path to environment variable.

Comment: @H_alt If the answer was correct or helpful please accept the answer or upvote it so that it would be helpful for me and others who will face same problem in future.