# setx command not recognized on Windows10

Tags: windows-10, setx

I am installing software on a new laptop with (unfortunately) Windows 10 and the `setx` command is not recognized:

> 'setx' is not recognized as an internal or external command

I have Googled this, but can't find anything related to setx and Windows-10.

Do I need to do something specific to enable this command on Windows-10?

Comment: How are you using the command?

Comment: "Using" is a funny word to use since it does not recognize the command. But both just "setx" and "setx /?" gives the not recognized reply

Comment: Ok. didn't see that you already tried setx /?

Comment: already asked here: http://superuser.com/questions/1018513/setx-command-missing-in-windows10

Comment: Ok I saw this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16139520/what-is-the-location-of-the-setx-command-in-windows-7 and it says you need to check C:\Windows\System32 should be in your PATH env variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer was given by svasa. It is strange but it worked. The strange thing is that it always was defined in my path, but as "%SystemRoot%\system32". Capitalizing system32 solved the problem. But this was an all new laptop, so I assume this wrong setting came from Microsoft?

Answer (score 1):

In some cases, it might be because you are in powershell or some other terminal, not in the "command prompt" terminal (remember to open it with admin)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to run my batch file as Administrator or from an Administrator command prompt.