# Twitter page not loading

Tags: java, swing, twitter, javafx

I am coding a small java swing app where we can view full web pages inside a javafx panel.I have tested almost all the popular web pages like google,facebook or yahoo as usual.I want to view the twitter page also.But the panel can not load the twitter page.Only the blank panel we get.Here is the code snippet that loads the desired web-page-

```
    private static void loadPage(final JFXPanel fxPanel2) 
    {
    Group group = new Group();
    Scene scene = new Scene(group);
    fxPanel2.setScene(scene);

    WebView webView = new WebView();

    group.getChildren().add(webView);
    webView.setMinSize(600,300 );
    webView.setMaxSize(600,300);

        // Obtain the webEngine to navigate
    WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
    webEngine.load("https://www.twitter.com/");
}
```

I would appreciate if I could get any solution to it.Thanks.

Comment: What happens? Does it throw an exception? It shows a blank page?

Comment: No exception,no error.Only a blank panel.In place of the address I tried putting other address also.It could load them normally.Except for twiiter.

Comment: You can use the getDocument() method of WebEngine to look inside the DOM of the loaded page. Try also to use HTTP instead of HTTPS

Comment: I have tried that also,but no use.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have some proxy settings preventing the access. 
You might want to take a look at this answer [Autodetect proxy - JavaFX - webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15575276/autodetect-proxy-javafx-webview)

Comment: My problem is solved now.The issue was because of an outdated version of java platform.After setting my IDE to the latest version I was able to view the twitter page in a normal window.