# JavaFX webview shows blank page on certain website

Tags: java, javafx, webview

i am struggeling with some problem here to load a website into the webviewer.

I followed the code from 
 [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/embedded-browser-tutorial/add-browser.htm) and changed it towards

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class WebViewSample extends Application {
    private Scene scene;
    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
          //   create the scene
        scene = new Scene(new Browser(),900,600, Color.web("#666970"));
        stage.setScene(scene);
         stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }
}
class Browser extends Region {

    final WebView browser = new WebView();
    final WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();

    public Browser() {

        webEngine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
           //  load the web page
        webEngine.load("https://www.immomapping.com/");
          //  add the web view to the scene
        getChildren().add(browser);
    }
}
```

It shows me just a blank page. I tried to check for [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15575276/autodetect-proxy-javafx-webview) proxies but aint going anywhere.

Can somebody help me?
The [website](https://www.immomapping.com/) is in german but should not matter.

Or does somebody know how to operate on Websites (opened in a browser, e.g. internet explorer :X ) like it is able to do with VBA?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

The reason is HTTPS protocol and you have certificate problem

Here are similar problems 
[JavaFX WebView can't load certain sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30784763/javafx-webview-cant-load-certain-sites)

[JavaFx Webview JDK 8 can not load self signed certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29655977/javafx-webview-jdk-8-can-not-load-self-signed-certificate)

Comment: Wow man, thanks! The second link really made the difference.

I copied the code from the Trustmanager, that Viet posted and it worked fine.

The thing with the TSL 1.0 or 1.2 version made no difference for me. I forgot to mention that i use JDK 1.8.