# JGit proxy configuration in code

Tags: java, proxy, jgit

I am able to clone repo using clone command in JGit

Repo is http and of course it's failing to clone when I am behind proxy

Could you help me with code sample how to configure JGit with proxy in java

thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using the classical way of setting an HTTP proxy at the JVM level?

Comment: as mention in the question, I need to set it up in code...

Comment: The question really was if it worked if you used the standard way. Your question does not really tell.

Answer (score 12):

JGit uses the standard `ProxySelector` mechanism for the Http connection.
As of Today, the field `org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.proxySelector` used by the framework, is not overridable. It is configurable, though, customizing the JVM default proxy selector as in:

```
ProxySelector.setDefault(new ProxySelector() {
    final ProxySelector delegate = ProxySelector.getDefault();

    @Override
    public List<Proxy> select(URI uri) {
            // Filter the URIs to be proxied
        if (uri.toString().contains("github")
                && uri.toString().contains("https")) {
            return Arrays.asList(new Proxy(Type.HTTP, InetSocketAddress
                    .createUnresolved("localhost", 3128)));
        }
        if (uri.toString().contains("github")
                && uri.toString().contains("http")) {
            return Arrays.asList(new Proxy(Type.HTTP, InetSocketAddress
                    .createUnresolved("localhost", 3129)));
        }
            // revert to the default behaviour
        return delegate == null ? Arrays.asList(Proxy.NO_PROXY)
                : delegate.select(uri);
    }

    @Override
    public void connectFailed(URI uri, SocketAddress sa, IOException ioe) {
        if (uri == null || sa == null || ioe == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Arguments can't be null.");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you using localhost as a placeholder where we should configure a value for the proxy address, or is it localhost?

Comment: Yes, substitute localhost/3128 with the host and port of your proxy

Answer (score 3):

In complement of Carlo Pellegrini answer, if your proxy requires some authentication, you should configure an `Authenticator`, like (based on [Authenticated HTTP proxy with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626549/authenticated-http-proxy-with-java) question):

```
    Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
        @Override
        public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            // If proxy is non authenticated for some URLs, the requested URL is the endpoint (and not the proxy host)
            // In this case the authentication should not be the one of proxy ... so return null (and JGit CredentialsProvider will be used)
            if (super.getRequestingHost().equals("localhost")) {
                return new PasswordAuthentication("foo", "bar".toCharArray());
            }
            return null;
        }
    });

    ProxySelector.setDefault(new ProxySelector() {...});
```