# WS Client with Proxy and Autentification

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, webservices-client, jax-ws-customization

I know this isn't exactly the correct way to ask a question, but I'm having a problem:

I have a wsdl stored locally, and I need to create a Web Service Client to call that Web Service. The problem is the service is behind a firewall and I have to connect to it through a proxy and after that I have to authentify to connect to the WS.

What i did is generate the WS Client with Apache CXF 2.4.6 then set a system wide proxy

```
System.getProperties().put("proxySet", "true");
System.getProperties().put("https.proxyHost", "10.10.10.10");
System.getProperties().put("https.proxyPort", "8080");
```

I know this isn't a best practice, so please suggest a better solution, also if anyone can give me a tip on how to set the authentification I'dd really appreciate it

Answer (score 21, accepted):

With apache CXF

```
HelloService hello = new HelloService();
HelloPortType helloPort = cliente.getHelloPort();
org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(helloPort);
HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();
http.getClient().setProxyServer("proxy");
http.getClient().setProxyServerPort(8080);
http.getProxyAuthorization().setUserName("user proxy");
http.getProxyAuthorization().setPassword("password proxy");
```

Answer (score 7):

If you´re using Spring Java configuration, to configure a JAX-WS Client with Apache CXF (3.x.x), the following code will work:

```
import org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client;
import org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean;
import org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import de.codecentric.namespace.weatherservice.WeatherService;

@Configuration
public class WeatherServiceConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public WeatherService weatherService() {
        JaxWsProxyFactoryBean jaxWsFactory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
        jaxWsFactory.setServiceClass(WeatherService.class);
        jaxWsFactory.setAddress("http://yourserviceurl.com/WeatherSoapService_1.0");
        return (WeatherService) jaxWsFactory.create();
    }

    @Bean
    public Client client() {
        Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(weatherService());
        HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();
        http.getClient().setProxyServer("yourproxy");
        http.getClient().setProxyServerPort(8080); // your proxy-port
        return client;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is the corresponding Spring XML configuration :

Documentation : http://cxf.apache.org/docs/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:http-conf="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration"
  xmlns:sec="http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/security"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
                      http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/http-conf.xsd
                      http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/security http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/security.xsd">

<http-conf:conduit name="*.http-conduit"> 
    <http-conf:client ProxyServer="proxy" ProxyServerPort="8080"/>

    <http-conf:proxyAuthorization> 
        <sec:UserName>proxy_user</sec:UserName> 
        <sec:Password>proxy_pass</sec:Password> 
    </http-conf:proxyAuthorization> 
</http-conf:conduit>
```

In order for this to work you should import cxf.xml :

```
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml"/>
```

Note that this httpConduit will be enabled for all your CXF clients (if several).

You should configure your conduit name to match only your service Conduit :

```
name="{http://example.com/}HelloWorldServicePort.http-conduit"
```

Comment: proxy host = `ProxyServer` property, port = `ProxyServerPort` property, seems that I don't understand your question

Answer (score 0):

You can also set proxy username and password using java.net.Authenticator class, but I am not sure if it is not "system wide" setting.

Look here:
[Authenticated HTTP proxy with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626549/authenticated-http-proxy-with-java/1626616#1626616)