# proxy authentication required in azure table using java

Tags: java, eclipse, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I need to access azure cloud table using java. My internet works behind proxy and needs authentication. I searched on internet and found this -

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "172.16.2.1");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "3128");
System.setProperty("http.proxyUser", "username");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPassword", "password");
```

but it gives the following error,

The Azure storage client library sample TableBasics starting...
Got an exception from running samples. Exception details:
com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.core.storage.StorageException: The server encountered an unknown failure: **Proxy Authentication Required**
    at com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.core.storage.StorageException.translateException(StorageException.java:129)
    at com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.core.storage.utils.implementation.StorageOperation.materializeException(StorageOperation.java:158)
    at com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.core.storage.utils.implementation.ExecutionEngine.executeWithRetry(ExecutionEngine.java:142)
    at com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.table.client.QueryTableOperation.performRetrieve(QueryTableOperation.java:218)
    at com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.table.client.TableOperation.execute(TableOperation.java:562)
    at com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.table.client.CloudTableClient.execute(CloudTableClient.java:262)
    at com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.table.client.CloudTable.exists(CloudTable.java:416)
    at com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.table.client.CloudTable.createIfNotExist(CloudTable.java:223)
    at com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.table.client.CloudTable.createIfNotExist(CloudTable.java:186)
    at test1.TableBasics.main(TableBasics.java:63)

The Azure storage client library sample TableBasics completed.

Comment: It looks like your proxy authentication code isn't working. You may need to use java.net.Authenticator as per another stackoverflow thread here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626549/authenticated-http-proxy-with-java.
If you suspect that this might be an issue with the Azure SDK, could you share a Fiddler trace of this request to see what is happening on the wire? A short code sample reproducing this error would also be helpful (but please do not share your passwords or secret keys).

Comment: thanks for this. I am now getting some other errors, but atleast I am now over this proxy authentication problem.

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils
 at com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.table.client.AtomPubParser.parseEntity(AtomPubParser.java:101) -- please help me with this... I don't know what this error means, and how to resolve this. any suggestions are highly appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

**Use "https" instead of "http" to proxy user and proxy password of system property**

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "172.16.2.1");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "3128");
System.setProperty("http.proxyUser", "username");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPassword", "password");
```

**instead of**

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "172.16.2.1");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "3128");
System.setProperty("https.proxyUser", "username"); // if domain name applicable then System.setProperty("https.proxyUser", "domain\\username");
System.setProperty("https.proxyPassword", "password");
```