# Google AppEngine maven application update

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine

While I'm trying to upload my maven AppEngine project to the google dev console using `appengine:update`, I get the exception below. My proxy is properly set up in maven's `settings.xml` because the dependencies were downloaded succesfuly. Also the project is working fine on the local server. Any ideas what could be the cause of the problem?

```
    INFO: Unable to access https://appengine.google.com/api/updatecheck?runtime=java
&release=1.9.18&timestamp=1423769416&api_versions=['1.0']
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketI
mpl.java:79)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.ja
va:339)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocket
Impl.java:200)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java
:182)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:625)
        at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:160
)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:275)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:371)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewH
ttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConne
ction.java:933)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect
(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLCon
nection.java:1301)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Http
sURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
        at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1037)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.info.RemoteVersionFactory.getVersion(Remot
eVersionFactory.java:76)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.info.UpdateCheck.getApplicationVersionInfo
(UpdateCheck.java:153)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.info.UpdateCheck.maybePrintNagScreen(Updat
eCheck.java:361)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.<init>(AppCfg.java:189)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.<init>(AppCfg.java:128)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.main(AppCfg.java:124)
        at com.google.appengine.appcfg.AbstractAppCfgMojo.executeAppCfgCommand(A
bstractAppCfgMojo.java:250)
        at com.google.appengine.appcfg.Update.execute(Update.java:32)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(Default
BuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:208)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThre
adedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(Lifecycl
eStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Laun
cher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.jav
a:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(La
uncher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:
356)

Please enter code: 4/V5TzBQzOQLxtII2MJCaA1lnE-ZVMqEcGpszvkqPWC7E.0rbx92WB4zwRyjz
_MlCJoi3gh4WrmAI
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was cause by the fact that maven was not reading my both http and https proxy entries from the `settings.xml` file. I putted only the http entry there and passed the https proxy trought the command line with `-Dhttps.proxyHost=<host> -Dhttps.proxyPort=<port>`.

Comment: Some people may need to set their proxy user and password http://stackoverflow.com/a/1626625/3677175