# SOCKS5 authentication with OkHTTP fails

Tags: java, okhttp, socks

I'm trying to get SOCKS5 proxy working with authentication in OkHTTP.

Authentication works fine for HTTP proxies using the following code:

```java
proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("host", 1000));

Authenticator proxyAuthenticator = new Authenticator() {
    @Override
    public Request authenticate(Route route, Response response) throws IOException {
        String credential = Credentials.basic("username", "password");
        return response.request().newBuilder()
                                 .header("Proxy-Authorization", credential)
                                 .build();
        }
    };

    client = defaultClient(key, timeout)
        .newBuilder()
        .proxyAuthenticator(proxyAuthenticator)
        .proxy(proxy)
        .build();
}
```

But when using `Proxy.Type.SOCKS` it throws `java.net.SocketException: SOCKS : authentication failed`.

I've found a few SO ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35554380/okhttpclient-proxy-authentication-how-to), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40011055/how-can-i-use-socks5-proxy-in-okhttp-to-start-http-request)) and GitHub [answers](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1773) on the topic but none have a working code example.

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: I'm using Java 17

Comment: And dependencies version?

Comment: It's OkHTTP 3.14.9