# java.net.ConnectException while running the following code using apache PDFBox

Tags: java, selenium

I'm getting java.net.ConnectException while running the below code. Can any one please help me?

package com.quantum.auto.common;

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper;


public class PDFReader {

    public void readPDFTest() throws IOException{
        URL url = new URL("https://www.betterteam.com/downloads/employee-information-form-download-20170810.pdf");
        //URLConnection urlcon = url.openConnection();
        InputStream is = url.openStream();
        BufferedInputStream fileParse = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        PDDocument document = null;

        document = PDDocument.load(fileParse);
        new PDFTextStripper().getText(document);
        String pdfContent = new PDFTextStripper().getText(document);
        System.out.println(pdfContent);

    }   
}
```

Comment: this code is working for me. are you behind a proxy? any FW rules?

Comment: I'm running this code on a VDI. There might be some proxy behind the scenes.

Comment: I suggest to login the proxy and check if you have connection to betterteam.com on port 443

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Authenticated HTTP proxy with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626549/authenticated-http-proxy-with-java)

Comment: This is not a PDFBox question, assuming the exception happens at the `openStream()` call. You should also edit your question to include the stack trace.

Comment: Ok, i'll try that. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Hi Adi, I'm able to hit the betterteram url directly (through browser). But, it's not hitting the url when i run the code. Any idea, why is it so?

Comment: Because your browser likely has a proxy configuration. Check the settings.

Comment: How is this question related to _Selenium_? Am I missing something?