# Telegram bot on Java not working with proxy

Tags: java, proxy, bots, telegram

```
       try {

           // Create the Authenticator that will return auth's parameters for proxy authentication
           Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
               @Override
               protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                   return new PasswordAuthentication(PROXY_USER, PROXY_PASSWORD.toCharArray());
               }
           });


       ApiContextInitializer.init();
       TelegramBotsApi telegramBotsApi = new TelegramBotsApi();

       // Set up Http proxy
       DefaultBotOptions botOptions = ApiContext
               .getInstance(DefaultBotOptions.class);


       botOptions.setProxyHost(PROXY_HOST);
       botOptions.setProxyPort(PROXY_PORT);
       //Select proxy type: [HTTP|SOCKS4|SOCKS5] (default: NO_PROXY)
       botOptions.setProxyType(DefaultBotOptions.ProxyType.HTTP);

       telegramBotsApi.registerBot(new MyBot(BOT_TOKEN, BOT_NAME, botOptions));
       } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
       //    e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
```

**This is my main method, but I'm getting the following error:**

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InternalError: Should not reach
>   here  at
>   java.net.HttpConnectSocketImpl.doTunneling(HttpConnectSocketImpl.java:181)
>     at
>   java.net.HttpConnectSocketImpl.doTunnel(HttpConnectSocketImpl.java:168)
>     at
>   java.net.HttpConnectSocketImpl.access$200(HttpConnectSocketImpl.java:44)
>     at
>   org.telegram.telegrambots.util.WebhookUtils.clearWebhook(WebhookUtils.java:74)
>     at
>   org.telegram.abilitybots.api.bot.AbilityBot.clearWebhook(AbilityBot.java:42)
>     at
>   org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.TelegramBotsApi.registerBot(TelegramBotsApi.java:120)
>     at Main.main(Main.java:49) Caused by:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   java.net.HttpConnectSocketImpl.doTunneling(HttpConnectSocketImpl.java:179)
>     ... 27 more Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException     at
>   java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(StringTokenizer.java:349)     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.doTunneling(HttpURLConnection.java:2072)
>     ... 32 more

My proxy is working, but I'm still getting this error. When I deployed this code to Heroku, it's working.

Comment: maybe [Authenticated HTTP proxy with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1626549/85421) helps