# Trying to use a Authenticated HTTP proxy in Java

Tags: java, squid

I was trying to connect to internet with a Squid HTTP Proxy with Java, I looked at

[Authenticated HTTP proxy with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626549/authenticated-http-proxy-with-java)

but that returns `Failed to authenticate with proxy`.
Here is my code so far:

```java
String proxyHost = config.getString("ProxyHost").trim();
        String proxyPort = config.getString("ProxyPort").trim();
        final String authUser = config.getString("ProxyUser").trim();
        final String authPassword = config.getString("ProxyPw").trim();

        if (!proxyHost.isEmpty() && proxyHost != null) {
            DiscordSRV.debug("Proxy host setting to " + proxyHost);

            Authenticator.setDefault(
                    new Authenticator() {
                        @Override
                        public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                            return new PasswordAuthentication(authUser, authPassword.toCharArray());
                        }
                    });

            try {

                System.setProperty("jdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes", "");
                // HTTP proxy
                System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", proxyHost);
                System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", proxyPort);
                System.setProperty("http.proxyUser", authUser);
                System.setProperty("http.proxyPassword", authUser);

                // HTTPS proxy
                System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", proxyHost);
                System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", proxyPort);
                System.setProperty("https.proxyUser", authUser);
                System.setProperty("https.proxyPassword", authUser);

                DiscordSRV.debug("Proxy successfully set");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                DiscordSRV.debug("Proxy settings failed to apply");
            }
        }
```

I have already tested the proxy with cURL and the proxy works fine.

Comment: You're setting your password to the user name.

Comment: I corrected that by `System.setProperty("https.proxyPassword", authPassword);` but that still gives `java.io.IOException: Failed to authenticate with proxy`

Comment: Did you fix "http.proxyPassword" as well?

Comment: Yes I did, `System.setProperty("http.proxyPassword", authPassword);`

Comment: I add some `System.out.println()` and is seem that it print the username and password correctly

Comment: I found from squid connection log that all the connections that fails have no username but the connection tested with cURL is with username, does that mean I didnt set username correctly?