# maven in 5 min not working

Tags: maven-2, maven

I have downloaded latest

> maven 3.0.3, java version "1.6.0_18".
>
> mvn –version

```
Apache Maven 3.0.3 (r1075438; 2011-02-28 18:31:09+0100)
    Maven home: C:\software\apache-maven-3.0.3
    Java version: 1.5.0_05, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
    Java home: C:\software\jdk1.5.0.15\jre
    Default locale: en_GB, platform encoding: Cp1252
    OS name: "windows xp", version: "5.1", arch: "x86", family: "windows"
```

My application located at: C:\Temp\ecm_esv\app\ENT_APP\ESV>. I am getting following error message:

```
C:\Temp\ecm_esv\app\ENT_APP\ESV>mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.4.1/maven-clean-plugin-2.4.1.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.4.1
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/2.3.1/maven-install-plugin-2.3.1.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.3.1: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.3.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:jar:2.3.1
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/2.5/maven-deploy-plugin-2.5.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.5: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:jar:2.5
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-site-plugin/2.0.1/maven-site-plugin-2.0.1.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:2.0.1: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:2.0.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:jar:2.0.1
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/1.3/maven-antrun-plugin-1.3.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:jar:1.3
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/2.2-beta-5/maven-assembly-plugin-2.2-beta-5.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:jar:2.2-beta-5
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/2.1/maven-dependency-plugin-2.1.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:jar:2.1
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-release-plugin/2.0/maven-release-plugin-2.0.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.0: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:jar:2.0
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Error transferring file: repo1.maven.org
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Error transferring file: repo1.maven.org
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Error transferring file: repo1.maven.org
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Error transferring file: repo1.maven.org
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.406s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Apr 18 15:51:05 CEST 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 1M/3M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'archetype' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Temp\ecm_esv\app\ENT_APP\ESV), central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException
C:\Temp\ecm_esv\app\ENT_APP\ESV>
```

C:\software\apache-maven-3.0.3\conf\settings.xml
I have enabled proxies here as:

```
….


<proxies>
    <!-- proxy
     | Specification for one proxy, to be used in connecting to the network.
     |-->
    <proxy>
      <id>optional</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>      
      <host>www.BT.co.uk</host>
      <port>80</port>
      <nonProxyHosts>localhost|google.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>

  </proxies>
```

What is the problem I am facing here? Why it is not downloading?

Comment: Nice question with all relevant information provided. Please add your solution also as an answer and accept so someone else having this problem has an easier time finding it.

Comment: For all those that still need an outline: http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Found solution:

**Solution #1:**

issue was with proxy in settings.xml file:

```
<host>webproxy</host>
```

to get host goto IE->tools->connection->LAN settings->advanced->http.

=====

**Solution #2:**

if auto configured proxy is given: then

1> open IE(or any browser)

2> get the url address from your browser through IE->Tools->internet option->connections->LAN Settings-> get address and give in url eg: as **http://autocache.abc.com/** and enter, a file will be downloaded with .pac format, save to desktop

3> open .pac file in textpad, identify PROXY:

In your editor, it will come something like:

```
   return "PROXY web-proxy.ind.abc.com:8080; PROXY proxy.sgp.abc.com:8080";
```

4> go to Maven settings.xml and enter as:

```
<proxy>
      <id>optional</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>          
      <host>web-proxy.ind.abc.com</host>
      <port>8080</port>          
</proxy>
```

5> run **mvn:install** through command prompt or run through eclipse.

=====

**Solution #3:**

For any other issues delete maven local repository and run **mvn:install** again.

Comment: Also uncomment the proxies tag

Answer (score 1):

Clearly this is an issue of proxy. Either use VPN or edit procy setting in setting.xml.
I searched lot about this error. Finally, I used VPN(Virtual private network ) to disable the proxy and was able to use cemtral repository of Maven.

Answer (score 1):

Window-Preferences-Maven-User Settings. Check, does settings.xml exists? if eclipse says no, get settings.xml from you friend or set the path to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking proxy settings in settings.xml file located under following directory:

C:\Users\UserName\.m2

Answer (score 0):

I just copied setting.xml which comes under "\apache-maven-3.1.1\conf" directory, to the directory "${user.home}/.m2/)" of windows machine and change the required proxy setting according to my network as below and it worked for me.

```
<proxy>
  <id>optional</id>
  <active>true</active>
  <protocol>http</protocol>
  <host>www-proxy.xxxx</host>
  <port>8080</port>
</proxy>
```

Thanks -- 
Kamran Shahzad

Answer (score 0):

We have observed that the maven project creation fails when it tries to download the archtype from this URL: [Maven Repository](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/archetypes/maven-archetype-quickstart/1.1/maven-archetype-quickstart-1.1.pom) which falls under **"https"** protocol.

So solution #2 mentioned above worked only after a little change to the ***settings.xml***. Instead of using "http" protocol I have to use **"https"**

```
<proxy>
  <id>optional</id>
  <active>true</active>
  <protocol>https</protocol>          
  <host>web-proxy.ind.abc.com</host>
  <port>8080</port>
```

Hope it helps someone.

Note: Make sure that you check  the following internet settings.

Internet Explorer > Internet Options > Connections [TAB] > LAN Settings > Under Proxy server check Use proxy server for LAN > Advanced > Check "same proxy server for all protocols" and Click OK.

Answer (score 0):

Adding below under proxy tag in settings.xml worked for me

```
<proxy>
  <id>optional</id>
  <active>true</active>
  <protocol>https</protocol>          
  <host>web-proxy.ind.abc.com</host>
  <port>8080</port>  
</proxy>
```