# m2e Eclipse indigo gives error

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have setup Maven project locally without eclipse, it is completed succefully.
Now i have downloaded Eclipse indgo 3.7.0. Since Eclipse-indigo is having m2e(maven 2 eclipse )plugin enabled it by

Eclipse->help->install new software->work with(Indigo - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo)->General purpose tools->m2e(check) and install.

in eclipse added project as as maven project, but i am getting error while running pom.xml file:

```
Downloading: http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.4.3/maven-resources-plugin-2.4.3.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.625s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Sep 15 12:33:01 CEST 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.4.3: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.4.3 from/to ibiblio.org (http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2): null to http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.4.3/maven-resources-plugin-2.4.3.pom: UnresolvedAddressException -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

this is m2e plugin issue, how can i solve this error?

also getting following error while importing exsisting maven project to eclipse:

```
Could not calculate build plan
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.4.1 or one of its dependencies 
could not be resolved: Transfer error: null
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:maven-plugin:2.4.1

from the specified remote repositories:
ibiblio.org (http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2, releases=true, snapshots=false)
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Could not calculate build plan: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.4.3 
    from http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of ibiblio.org has elapsed or 
    updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.4.3 from/to ibiblio.org 
    (http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2): null to http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.4.3/maven-resources-
    plugin-2.4.3.pom    my-app      Unknown Maven Problem
```

POM.xml:

```xml
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.test.myapp</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>my-app</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
</project>
```

Comment: How does your settings.xml file look like? It seemed to me that you changed the settings.xml in some way...but you shouldn't cause ibiblio is not Maven Central i would suggest to use http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ instead.

Comment: Have you checked to build your project on command line just mvn clean package ?

Comment: @khmarbaise, from cmd maven is working fine. only problem is with eclipse plugin m2e.

Comment: i just downloaded maven, changed repository path in conf as:  <localRepository>/C:/software/maven repository</localRepository>. all other remain same.

Comment: Why does your maven download from ibiblio instead of Maven Central if you didn't change other things ? I would suggest to clean your local repository (as described above) and do an other time on command line...BTW: Which version of Maven are you using on Command Line ?

Comment: Apache Maven 3.0.3
Maven home: C:\software\apache-maven

Comment: Have you declared the maven implementation you want to use in m2e? If you don't do that, Eclipse has no chance to use the Maven settings you have declared.

Comment: go to maven settings.xml file and enable proxy.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5704010/maven-in-5-min-not-working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solved, issue was since working in an organization( where proxy enabled), enabled proxy in settings.xml as given by
[maven in 5 min not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5704010/maven-in-5-min-not-working)

Answer (score 5):

Check the sha1 checksums in `org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/` under your local repository and delete the `maven-resources-plugin` directory if any of them are wrong. Or just delete the directory and let the maven to download it again.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse has a built-in Maven implementation. Try to compile the project from command line with the same Maven version as Eclipse has or set your Maven installation in Eclipse (Window / Preferences / Maven / Installations).

Comment: when i compile from cmd it is working fine as I had informed in my question

Comment: The version of your command line Maven is the same as Eclipse has? (Usually 3.0-SNAPSHOT) Have you tried to change your Eclipse's Maven?

Comment: i have changed repository location and settings.xml from eclipse->window->preference->Maven->user settings. How can i change maven location in eclipse?

Comment: Eclipse / Window / Preferences / Maven / Installations