# PlayN samples imported into Eclipse won't build

Tags: eclipse, maven, playn

I get errors when installing the sample projects from the PlayN getting started page ([http://code.google.com/p/playn/wiki/GettingStarted][1]). I have all Android SDKs, Maven plugsins for Eclipse, etc. Here's the output from Eclipse:

> "Could not calculate build plan: Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
>   for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.4.3 Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
>   for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.4.3"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you append the relevant `mvn -X ...` output to your post?

Answer (score 0):

That error has nothing to do with PlayN. This question might help you resolve the issue:

[m2e Eclipse indigo gives error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7430682/m2e-eclipse-indigo-gives-error)