# maven: Error transferring file: Connection refused: connect

Tags: maven, maven-2

I am working in a network environment. 
my network ip address for internet is:

IE->tools->internet options->connections->LAN settings->Use Automatic configuration script(enabled): Address: **http://autocache.abc.com/**

port address is not specified in IE settings.

when i do ping autocache.abc.com it gives following ip address: 16.234.18.243

in settings.xml file i have enabled entry for proxy as:

```
<proxy>
         <id>genproxy</id>
         <active>true</active>
         <protocol>http</protocol>
         <host>autocache.abc.com</host>
</proxy>
```

Nothing is specified at Ie host ie: IE->tools->connection->LAN settings->advanced->http shows empty

if i run **mvn install** getting following error:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building home-app
[INFO]    task-segment: [install]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 4 resources
Downloading: https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases//org/springframework/spring-parent/3.0.6.RELEASE/spring-parent-3.0.6.RELEASE.pom
[WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.springframework:spring-parent:pom:3.0.6.RELEASE' from repository jboss (https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/): Error transferring file: Connection refused: connect
Downloading: http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release/org/springframework/spring-parent/3.0.6.RELEASE/spring-parent-3.0.6.RELEASE.pom
[WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.springframework:spring-parent:pom:3.0.6.RELEASE' from repository com.springsource.repository.bundles.release (http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release): Error transferring file: Connection refused: connect
Downloading: http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external/org/springframework/spring-parent/3.0.6.RELEASE/spring-parent-3.0.6.RELEASE.pom
[WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.springframework:spring-parent:pom:3.0.6.RELEASE' from repository com.springsource.repository.bundles.external (http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external): Error transferring file: Connection refused: connect
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-parent/3.0.6.RELEASE/spring-parent-3.0.6.RELEASE.pom
[WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.springframework:spring-parent:pom:3.0.6.RELEASE' from repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Error transferring file: Connection refused: connect
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error building POM (may not be this project's POM).


Project ID: org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:3.0.6.RELEASE

Reason: Cannot find parent: org.springframework:spring-parent for project: org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:3.0.6.RELEASE for project org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:3.0.6.RELEASE


[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 11 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Feb 15 11:40:32 IST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/27M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If I run mvn install without network connection ie at my private internet connection, it is working fine and only problem is with network proxy.

I strongly feel it is host issue, if I give host as  16.234.18.243 instead of autocache.abc.com, still gives same error.

I tried to create new local repository( ie deleted existing directory), but still same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1> open IE(or any browser),

2> give url as **http://autocache.abc.com/** ( you have given above) and enter, a file will be downloaded with .pac format, save to desktop

3> open .pac file in textpad, identify PROXY:

In your editor, it will come something like:

```
   return "PROXY web-proxy.ind.abc.com:8080; PROXY proxy.sgp.abc.com:8080";
```

4> go to Maven settings.xml and enter as:

```
<proxy>
      <id>optional</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>          
      <host>web-proxy.ind.abc.com</host>
      <port>8080</port>          
</proxy>
```

5> run mvn:install through command prompt or run through eclipse.

go through [maven-in-5-min-not-working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5704010/maven-in-5-min-not-working)

Answer (score 4):

The URL you specified most likely contains a [Proxy auto-config](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config) file . You need to download it and see what the proxy settings specified in it are.

For instance, the file contents

```
   function FindProxyForURL(url, host)
   {
      return "PROXY proxy.example.com:8080; DIRECT";
   }
```

indicates that you should use the proxy server `proxy.example.com` on port 8080.

For a more elaborate example, see [How to configure Maven behind an auto configured proxy](http://www.java-tutorial.ch/maven/how-to-configure-maven-behind-an-auto-configured-proxy)  .