# Failed to resolve version for org.apache.maven.archetypes

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I have configured maven3.0.3 in my local machine. Have installed m2e eclipse plugin.
But when i try to create a new maven project using maven-archetype-webapp, i get the following exception.

```
 Could not resolve archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:RELEASE    from any of the configured repositories.
 Could not resolve artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype- webapp:pom:RELEASE
 Failed to resolve version for org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype- webapp:pom:RELEASE: Could not find metadata org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype- webapp/maven-metadata.xml in local ([HOME]/.m2/repository)
 Failed to resolve version for org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-  webapp:pom:RELEASE: Could not find metadata org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-  webapp/maven-metadata.xml in local ([HOME]/.m2/repository)
```

I do some processing behind a proxy and the proxy configurations are updated in      `{HOME}/.m2/settings.xml and M2_HOME/conf/settings.xml.`

The archetype generate command works fine in command line. It downloaded the dependencies through proxy.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit 05-10-2012
While creating a new Maven Web project in eclipse, the archetype "maven-archetype-webapp" version is displayed as RELEASE. Is this in anyway linked?

Comment: org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:RELEASE this look strange ? Are you sure having the correct version? (http://search.maven.org/#search|gav|1|g%3A%22org.apache.maven.archetypes%22%20AND%20a%3A%22maven-archetype-webapp%22)

Comment: @khmarbaise The scenario happens when im trying create a maven project in eclipse. I have tried installing the plugin from [link](http://eclipse.org/m2e/download/). The result was same. Then i tried to follow the instructions in [link](http://www.rarejava.com/blog/2011/03/maven-integration-for-eclipse)

Comment: The eclipse message does say **Could not find metadata org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp/maven-metadata.xml in local ({HOME}/.m2/repository** . Can there be any reason that eclipse isnt downloading maven-metadata.xml. The proxy works because I have installed the m2e plugin online. Any hints or directions?

Comment: You should try it on command line first.

Comment: @khmarbaise The command executed succeffully on the commandline **mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-webapp -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp** and a web project was created. Im still unable to do it from Eclipse.

Comment: I had a syntax error in settings.xml. Fixing the error solved the issue.

Answer (score 55):

I had the same problem. I fixed it by adding the maven [archetype catalog](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/specification/archetype-catalog.html) to eclipse. Steps are provided below:

1. Open Window > Preferences
2. Open Maven > Archetypes
3. Click 'Add Remote Catalog' and add the following:

   - Catalog File: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml
   - Description: maven catalog

Comment: Your solution didn't work for me. Finally I solved the problem: See detailed steps at my response at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25760961/cannot-create-maven-project-in-eclipse/25807975#25807975

Comment: Error while adding the catalog file: An internal error occurred during Downloading reomte catalog

Comment: while adding remote catalog when I click on verify it says `Remote catalog is empty`, if I continue anyway its not working

Comment: This worked for me, but then I started getting OOM exception in eclipse, because it starts pulling out the list of all the archtypes from the remote server, which takes some memory. I had to increase -Xmx in eclipse.ini, so we need to make sure that eclipse already has enough memory allocated.

Comment: Though this works, but sometimes some other issue could make this solution ineffective. I had the issue with mirrors in my maven settings.xml. Once I commented out those in settings.xml, it worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

I found the following [tutorial](http://www.javahotchocolate.com/tutorials/maven.html) very useful.

Step1: The maven command used to create the web app:
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=test.aasweb -DartifactId=TestWebApp -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp

Step2: The following entry was added onto the project's pom.xml.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
    <configuration>
    <source>1.6</source>
    <target>1.6</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
    <wtpapplicationxml>true</wtpapplicationxml>
    <wtpversion>1.5</wtpversion>
    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
        <classpathContainers>
            <classpathContainer>
                org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.web.container
            </classpathContainer>
            <classpathContainer>
                org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.module.container
            </classpathContainer>
        /classpathContainers>
        <additionalProjectFacets>
            <jst.web>2.5</jst.web>
            <jst.jsf>1.2</jst.jsf>
        </additionalProjectFacets>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Step3: Run the maven command to convert into eclipse project format.
     mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse

Step4: Import the project onto eclipse as Existing Maven project.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using eclipse, you can follow the steps here ([maven in 5 min not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5704010/maven-in-5-min-not-working)) for getting your proxy information. Once done follow the steps below:

1. Go to Maven installation folder `C:\apache-maven-3.1.0\conf\`
2. Copy `settings.xml` to `C:\Users\[UserFolder]\.m2`
3. Modify the proxy in `settings.xml` based on the info that you get from the above link.

   > ```
   > <proxy>
   >   <active>true</active>
   >   <protocol>http</protocol>
   >   <host>your proxy</host>
   >   <port>your port</port>
   > </proxy>
   > ```
4. Open eclipse
5. Go to: Windows > Preferences > Maven > User Settings
6. Browse the `settings.xml` from `.m2` folder
7. Click `Update Settings`
8. Click `Reindex`
9. Apply the changes and Click `OK`

You can now try to create Maven Project in Eclipse

Answer (score 3):

Read carefully about the reason.

"Failed to resolve version for org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-  webapp:pom:RELEASE: Could not find metadata org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-  webapp/**maven-metadata.xml** in local"

So all you need to do is download the [maven-metadata.xml](http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml)
to your {HOME}.m2\repository

That's it.

Answer (score 3):

You do need to have a settings.xml linked under user settings (Located in preferences under maven)

But, if that doesn't fix it, like it didn't for many of you. You also have to delete the directory:

.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/archetypes/maven-archetype-quickstart

then quit eclipse and try again.

This is what solved my problem.

Comment: My problem was also solved just by pointing to the right settings.xml file. (Window/Preferences/Maven/User Settings)

Answer (score 1):

Go to Windows-> Preference-> Maven -> User settings

Select settings.xml of Maven

Restart Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem building from just command line Maven.  I eventually got past that error by adding -U to the maven arguments.

Depending on how you have your source repository configuration set up in your settings.xml, sometimes Maven fails to download a particular artifact, so it assumes that the artifact can't be downloaded, even if you change some settings that would give Maven visibility to the artifact if it just tried.  -U forces Maven to look again.

Now you need to make sure that the artifact Maven is looking for is in at least one of the repositories that is referenced by your settings.xml.  To know for sure, run

```
mvn help:effective-settings
```

from the directory of the module you are trying to build.  That should give you, among other things, a complete list of the repositories you Maven is using to look for the artifact.

Answer (score 0):

I too had same problem but after searching solved this. go to menu --> window-->preferences-->maven-->Installations-->add--> in place of installation home add path to the directory in which you installed maven-->finish-->check the box of newly added content-->apply-->ok. now create new maven project but remember try with different group id and artifact id.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to solve my problem are as followed. Hope to be helpful to others.
the errors informations.

`Could not resolve archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:1.0 from any of the configured repositories. Could not resolve artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:pom:1.0 Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:pom:1.0`

1. Delete the maven-archetype-webapp:1.0 in the directory ~/.m2/repository/org/Apache/maven/archetypes
2. Download the  maven-archetype-webapp:1.0 and the maven-archetype-webapp-1.0.pom    from 
    http://maven.ibiblio.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/archetypes/maven-archetype-webapp/1.0/
3. execute mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes -DartifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -Dversion=1.1 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=此处填maven-archetype-webapp-1.0的路径.
4. try to establish a maven project of webapp  to test whether the problem has solved.

Answer (score 0):

Create New User Environment Variables:

```
MAVEN_HOME=D:\apache-maven-3.5.3

MAVEN=D:\apache-maven-3.5.3\bin

MAVEN_OPTS=-Xms256m -Xmx512m
```

Appened below in Path variable (System Variable):

```
;D:\apache-maven-3.5.3\bin;
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:- navigate to windows-> preferences-> maven 
and check the "download artifacts sources" and click apply.

Answer (score 0):

No need to do all above lengthy steps.

Simply delete c:\Users\.m2\Repository\org folder

Maven will automatically downloads what it needs

Answer (score 0):

I simple use below steps:

Create Maven project -> check checkobox -> "Create a simple project (skip archetype selection)"

It works for me

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the jar and pom from:
[here](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/archetypes/maven-archetype-quickstart/1.1/)
and put them here:

```
\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\archetypes\maven-archetype-quickstart\1.1\
```

Answer (score 0):

I also got same error ....And i found that my internet connection is closed so eclipse is unable to download repositories for webapps archetypes and when i got internet connection i just created again maven project with webapps archetypes and my eclipse downloaded repositories and its done...

Answer (score 0):

This is 100% working:

- Delete the .m2 folder which is present in your Desktop>User
- connect  your pc to the Internet
- Create your maven project  again

Thats it, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try , It worked for = I just removed "archetypes" folder from below location

C:\Users\Lenovo.m2\repository\org\apache\maven

But you may change following for experiment - download latest binary zip of Maven, add to you C:\ drive and change following....

[image]

[image]

[image]

Change Proxy

```
 <proxy>
          <id>optional</id>
          <active>true</active>
          <protocol>http</protocol>
          <username></username>
          <password></password>
          <host>10.23.73.253</host>
          <port>8080</port>
          <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
        </proxy>
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem i solved it by only adding remote catalog 
    in  eclipse go to Window -> Preferences ->Maven ->Archetypes ->click on add remote Catalog then a window will open in that paste
http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml
in that catalog file then hit ok restart eclipse now all working fine

Answer (score -2):

The problem may also come from that you haven't set `MAVEN_HOME` environment variable. So the Maven embedded in Eclipse can't do its job to download the archetype.Check if that variable is set upfront.