# How to create MVC project in Kepler IDE

Tags: java, spring, maven, eclipse-kepler

I'm not able to find the zip file of Spring Framework. But on Stackoverflow I found that we can download the JARs using maven repo by configuring POM.xml. But by having the latest version of Eclipse IDE I was only able to get a folder named .m2 into that a repository folder and into that .cache and org, and so on. **No POM.xml**. So due to this I'm not able to create a Maven project or a Spring project.

Comment: You can download the Spring jars from here: http://repo.spring.io/simple/libs-release-local/org/springframework/

Comment: @eolit- But i also don't have POM.xml. My .m2 folder is not well organized as it should be for running the Maven project. Kindly help me with that also.

Comment: Downvoted for not bothering to read any of the beginner tutorials on the spring.io before asking.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Spring Tool Suite](http://spring.io/tools). It is eclipse with plugins added, made to work good with Spring.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first install maven with your eclipse via [m2e plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/) .

Then later run Maven clean/install on project to download and  build project jars automatically. You can see tutorial [here](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-java-project-with-maven/).

Comment: Imran-maven comes handy with Eclipse Kepler IDE, but still i'm not able to create project by using **maven-archetype-webapp** it displays an error message as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20027406/how-do-i-create-a-web-application-in-maven-using-kepler-ide)

Comment: might be the following help you..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12742467/failed-to-resolve-version-for-org-apache-maven-archetypes

Answer (score 1):

Don't download anything manually - use a dependency management framework such as Maven or Gradle.

Almost every guide on the spring.io web site provides details of what to put in the Maven pom.xml (or build.gradle). Here's one to get you started:

http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/