# Cannot create Maven Project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have Eclipse Luna and Maven 3.2.3 installed on a Windows 7 machine behind a corporate firewall.

Trying to create a project from an archetype results in the following error:

> Could not resolve archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:RELEASE from any of the configured repositories.
>
> Could not resolve artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:RELEASE
>
> Failed to resolve version for org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-
>   quickstart:pom:RELEASE:   Could not find metadata org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\xxxx.m2\repository)
>
> Failed to resolve version for org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:RELEASE: Could not find metadata org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\xxxx.m2\repository)

Proxy details are configured in `.m2/settings.xml` and generating a maven project from an archtype works fine in command line.

I tried to apply the solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506043/create-a-maven-project-in-eclipse-complains-could-not-resolve-archetype?lq=1) but none worked. The remote catalog is not acessible as well. I reckon it's a problem with the network settings of Eclipse. I also looked at [this bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=355774) to try and find some clues and couldn't really understand how to implement the workaround.

here is my settings.xml file:

```xml
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>nexus</id>
            <username>xxxx@xxxx.com</username>
            <password>{XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}</password>
        </server>
        <server>
            <id>deployment</id>
            <username>xxxx@xxxx.com</username>
            <password>{XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
    <mirrors>
        <mirror>
        <!--This sends everything else to /public -->
        <id>nexus</id>
        <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
        <url>https://nexus-int.xxxx.xxxx.com/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
        <id>nexus</id>
            <!--Enable snapshots for the built in central repo to direct -->
        <!--all requests to nexus via the mirror -->
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>central</id>
                <url>http://central</url>
                <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
                <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
        <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>central</id>
                <url>http://central</url>
                <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
                <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
            </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <activeProfiles>
        <!--make the profile active all the time -->
        <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Tomer

Comment: It looks like proxy problem. I have tried with the same configuration and able to generate quickstart. 
Go to your repository (.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\archetypes), delete maven-archetype-quickstart folder and try again(Make sure that your proxy is configured properly, it would be better if you can post settings.xml here). 

Otherwise get this jar from http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/maven/archetypes/maven-archetype-quickstart/1.1/maven-archetype-quickstart-1.1.jar and copy it manually.

Comment: o.k. I have an update! I removed the repository info for the internal repository and put only proxy information and it worked! something about the redirect to the internal corporate repository and confusing m2e, eventhough that repo is essentially a time-delayed mirror of central.

Comment: why there are so many archetypes? does anyone use anything other than quickstart? and why i have to learn all this just to get started with my work. Maven is HUGE distraction, demands toooo much attention than it deserves

Comment: @weima you have a point, but there is a work around.  When you create a maven project just check "Create a simple maven project (skip archetype selection)" and proceed.  This worked for me(I am a beginer in maven)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Same problem here, **solved**.

I will explain the problem and the solution, to help others.

My software is:

```
Windows 7
Eclipse 4.4.1 (Luna SR1)
m2e 1.5.0.20140606-0033
    (from eclipse repository: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna)
```

And I'm accessing internet through a proxy.

My **problem** was the same:

- Just installed m2e, went to menu: File > New > Other > Maven > Maven project > Next > Next.
- Selected "Catalog: All catalogs" and "Filter: maven-archetype-quickstart", then clicked on the search result, then on button Next.
- Then entered "Group Id: test_gr" and "Artifact Id: test_art", then clicked on Finish button.
- Got the "Could not resolve archetype..." error.

After a lot of try-and-error, and reading a lot of pages, I've finally found a solution to fix it. Some **important points** of the solution:

- It uses the default (embedded) Maven installation (3.2.1/1.5.0.20140605-2032) that comes with m2e.
- So no aditional (external) Maven installation is required.
- No special m2e config is required.

The **solution** is:

- Open eclipse.
- Restore m2e original preferences (if you changed any of them): Click on menu: Window > Preferences > Maven > Restore defaults. Do the same for all tree items under "Maven" item: Archetypes, Discovery, Errors/Warnings, Instalation, Lifecycle Mappings, Templates, User Interface, User Settings. Click on "OK" button.
- Copy (for example to a notepad window) the path of the user settings file. To see the path, click again on menu: Window > Preferences > Maven > User Settings, and the path is at the "User settings" textbox. You will have to write the path manually, since it is not posible to copy-and-paste. After coping the path to the notepad, don't close the Preferences window.
- At the Preferences window that is already open, click on the "open file" link. Close the Preferences window, and you will see the "settings.xml" file already openned in a Eclipse editor.
- The editor will have 2 tabs at the bottom: "Design" and "Source". Click on "Source" tab. You will see all the source code (xml).
- Delete all the source code: Click on the code, press control+a, press "del".
- Copy the following code to the editor (and customize the uppercased values):

> ```
> <settings>
>   <proxies>
>    <proxy>
>       <active>true</active>
>       <protocol>http</protocol>
>       <host>YOUR.PROXY.IP.OR.NAME</host>
>       <port>YOUR PROXY PORT</port>
>       <username>YOUR PROXY USERNAME (OR EMPTY IF NOT REQUIRED)</username>
>       <password>YOUR PROXY PASSWORD (OR EMPTY IF NOT REQUIRED)</password>
>       <nonProxyHosts>YOUR PROXY EXCLUSION HOST LIST (OR EMPTY)</nonProxyHosts>
>     </proxy>
>   </proxies>
> </settings>
> ```

- Save the file: control+s.
- Exit Eclipse: Menu File > Exit.
- Open in a Windows Explorer the path you copied (without the filename, just the path of directories).
- You will probaly see the xml file ("settings.xml") and a directoy ("repository"). Remove the directoy ("repository"): Right click > Delete > Yes.
- Start Eclipse.
- Now you will be able to create a maven project:  File > New > Other > Maven > Maven project > Next > Next, select "Catalog: All catalogs" and "Filter: maven-archetype-quickstart", click on the search result, then on button Next, enter "Group Id: test_gr" and "Artifact Id: test_art", click on Finish button.

Finally, I would like to give a **suggestion** to m2e developers, to make config easier. After installing m2e from the internet (from a repository), m2e should check if Eclipse is using a proxy (Preferences > General > Network Connections). If Eclipse is using a proxy, the m2e should show a dialog to the user:

```
m2e has detected that Eclipse is using a proxy to access to the internet.
Would you like me to create a User settings file (settings.xml) for the embedded 
Maven software?

[ Yes ] [ No ]
```

If the user clicks on Yes, then m2e should create automatically the "settings.xml" file by copying proxy values from Eclipse preferences.

Comment: I don't understand in what your solution is different from mine. It looks like you just added a proxy declaration to the user settings file. Am I correct? or did I miss anything. My problem is that I can figure out how to combine the proxy declaration with  a priority to download artifacts from the internal maven repo.

Comment: Well, perhaps your solution is similar to my solution, I just posted the thing that worked for me, that basically consists of: 1. Remove aditional (external) maven config from m2e config in eclipse; 2. Use only the maven that is embedded into m2e; 3. Restore all the original (default) config in m2e; 4. Remove all downloaded maven files ("repository" directory); 5. Create a settings.xml file with my proxy settings.

Comment: I have tried to do this many times before but failed.. your solution is so perfect.. it worked!

Comment: why is Maven so difficult to use? for me, dealing with unnecessary maven issues is enough to never work in java, and go back to simple life of C/C++. i hope Maven never creeps in to that world

Comment: This is a perfect solution

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution.

Comment: Thanks @freesoft, this is the best solution encountered so far. +1

Answer (score 36):

For me the solution was a bit simpler, I just had to clean the repository : .m2/repository/org/apache/maven/archetypes

Comment: I deleted that folder for 'archetypes-quickstart'  & it worked. I don't know why though.

Comment: Another thing i did is add proxy in settings.xml for protocol "https" also, struggling for long time on this.

Comment: Perfect solution for my issue

Answer (score 15):

Just delete the ${user.home}/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/archetypes to refresh all files needed, it worked fine to me!

Comment: its 2018 and i got the same problem solved by this answer man.
My eclipse version is Photon. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

I GOT THIS problem too, and I solved it finally, this is the solution:

> go to windows-->preference-->maven-->user settings

Change the `settings.xml` path to a valid path.

The path maybe not under .m2 directory (in your home directory)..

Answer (score 3):

**In my case following solution worked.**

1. Delete **RELEASE** directory & **resolver-status.properties** file in your local Maven repository under directory .m2/../maven-archetype-quickstart.
2. Create Maven project in Eclipse or STS (Spring Tool Suite). It will automatically download quickstart archetype & work as expected.

I hope this may help someone.

Answer (score 3):

It's actually easy and straight forward.

just navigate to your .m2 folder.

**.m2/repository/org/apache/maven**

inside this maven folder, you will see a folder called Archetypes... delete this folder and the problem is solved.

but if you don't feel like deleting the whole folder, you can navigate into the archetype folder and delete all the archetype you want there. The reason why it keeps failing is because, the archetype you are trying to create is trying to tell you that she already exists in that folder, hence move away...

summarily, deleting the archetype folder in the .m2 folder is the easiest solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error show up while creating the project but I wasn't behind a proxy and hence the above solutions did not work for me.

**I found [this forum](https://www.genuitec.com/forums/topic/could-not-resolve-archetype-when-creating-a-maven-project/). It suggested to:**

> 1. Delete or Rename .m2 directory from your HOME directory

`In Windows - C:\Users\<username>\Windows`

OR

```
In Linux - /home/<username>
```

> 2. restart the Eclipse / STS spring tool suite (which am using)

It worked!

Answer (score 0):

I am using Spring STS 3.8.3. I had a similar problem. I fixed it by using information from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12742467/failed-to-resolve-version-for-org-apache-maven-archetypes/15789286#15789286) And also by fixing some maven settings. click  Spring Tool Suite -> Preferences -> Maven and uncheck the box that says "Do not automatically update dependencies from remote depositories" Also I checked the boxes that say "Download Artifact Sources" and "download Artifact javadoc".

Answer (score 0):

If you're behind a proxy, the very first thing to do is, add `settings.xml` with proxy configs under `C:\Users\{username}\.m2` folder, and replicate same proxy configs under `Window > Preferences > Network Connections` (you may need to prefix your user name with domain eg. `DOMAIN\username`):

```
<settings>
  <proxies>
   <proxy>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>webproxy.net</host>
      <port>8080</port>
      <username>username</username>
      <password>password</password>
      <nonProxyHosts>localhost|127.0.0.1</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
   <proxy>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>https</protocol>
      <host>webproxy.net</host>
      <port>8080</port>
      <username>username</username>
      <password>password</password>
      <nonProxyHosts>localhost|127.0.0.1</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>    
  </proxies>
```

Delete `C:\Users\{username}\.m2\repository` folder as well.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for = I just removed "archetypes" folder from below location

C:\Users\Lenovo.m2\repository\org\apache\maven

But you may change following for experiment - download latest binary zip of Maven, add to you C:\ drive and change following....

[image]

[image]

[image]

Change Proxy

```
 <proxy>
          <id>optional</id>
          <active>true</active>
          <protocol>http</protocol>
          <username></username>
          <password></password>
          <host>10.23.73.253</host>
          <port>8080</port>
          <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
        </proxy>
```

Answer (score 0):

Today this issue, consumed nearly entire day of mine. Hence, thought to share learning if it can save time of others.

It seems Eclipse Luna had issue. I tried bunch of things, but problem remain unresolved with Eclipse Luna.

Subsequently, I tried Eclipse Neon and problem is auto-resolved with Neon. It seems when the issue was posted here (as it's quite old), Neon version may not have been released.

So in summary, If anyone is yet using Java-8, Maven than by using Eclipse Neon you should not face an issue.

Also, what I learnt is that Maven-be it embedded (Internal to Eclipse) or external (which we install separately) don't make any difference here.

So now my working stack - JDK 8, Maven 3, Eclipse Neon

Ref: Eclipse Neon link for download - https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/neon/3/eclipse-jee-neon-3-win32-x86_64.zip

PS - Also, I tried latest version of Eclipse (R) named as "eclipse-jee-2021-03-R-win32-x86_64", however it requires minimal version as Java-11, so for Java 8 we can't use it.