# Not able to create maven-archetype-quickstart project

Tags: eclipse, apache, maven, eclipse-plugin, m2eclipse

I am trying to create a Maven Project but I receive this error:

Could not resolve archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:RELEASE from any of the configured repositories.
Could not resolve artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:RELEASE
Failed to resolve version for org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:RELEASE: Could not find metadata org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart/maven-metadata.xml in local 
Failed to resolve version for org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:RELEASE: Could not find metadata org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart/maven-metadata.xml in local

I am using Eclipse Luna, Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.5.2.

I have tried to create a Remote Catalog in the archetypes, as well as used it as the global user settings but neither worked: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml

One thing I have noticed is, I did not find the settings.xml file in .m2 folder...

Any advice would be really appreciated

Comment: Check if you are beyond firewall..

Comment: Check this..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25760961/cannot-create-maven-project-in-eclipse