# error while creating maven project using eclipse mars

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-archetype

I am trying to create maven project with archetype maven-archetype-quickstart but i got the following errors :

```
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
```

I have installed maven properly. I tried to follow this solution [[Cannot create Maven Project in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25760961/cannot-create-maven-project-in-eclipse/25807975#25807975][1]), but i am confuse with setting.xml.

I am not using proxy connection so how can i configure proxy settings or is it mandatory to configure proxy connection ?

I tried to set the active from true to false and make empty both host and port since i am not using proxy.

Here is my settings.xml file according to the above link.

```
<settings>
  <proxies>
   <proxy>
      <active>false</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host></host>
      <port></port>
      <username>YOUR PROXY USERNAME (OR EMPTY IF NOT REQUIRED)</username>
      <password>YOUR PROXY PASSWORD (OR EMPTY IF NOT REQUIRED)</password>
      <nonProxyHosts>YOUR PROXY EXCLUSION HOST LIST (OR EMPTY)</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
</settings>
```

Any solution please?
Thanks

Comment: possibly the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39392546/could-not-calculate-build-plan

Comment: @justcurious. I do not get any pom.xml because whenever I tried to add archetype it gives error..however how to update local and global repository settings

Comment: So, all about the proxy problem in settings.xml file. can anyone help how to setup host and port for proxy in settings.xml. right now i am not in proxy connection. Thanks