# Could not calculate build plan:

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, pom.xml

Can anyone help me to resolve this error , whatever i do i am getting the same error again and again. 
my POM file is

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>SoapTestProject</groupId>
  <artifactId>SoapTestProject</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <pluginManagement>
     <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.4</source>
          <target>1.4</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

I am getting the below error message.

```
CoreException: Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.5.1: ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:3.5.1 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:3.5.1 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect timed out
```

Comment: are you building it from an ide or command line?

Comment: from eclipe neon , with java 1.8

Comment: first build it from a command line to verify everything is fine with your maven configuration. In Eclipse check the maven global and local repository settings.

Comment: thanks justcurious , it worked for me to update global setting