# Can not create Eclipse Neon Maven Project

Tags: eclipse, maven

I need your help.

I'm trying 2 days create maven project on eclipse neon but I get an error. I examined [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506043/create-a-maven-project-in-eclipse-complains-could-not-resolve-archetype) and [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25760961/cannot-create-maven-project-in-eclipse) and tried solutions but they doesn't help to me.

Here is the error :

> Could not resolve archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:1.1 from any of the configured repositories.
>   Could not resolve artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.1
>   Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.1 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org
>   Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.1 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org

I did proxy settings. What is my problem? How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you contact https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 at all from your computer?

Comment: Yes I can contact https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/ at all from my computer and intellij. I can't create maven project on eclipse neon.