# Maven not allowing me to create web app because of archetype problems

Tags: java, maven

I've been getting the "Could not resolve archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:1.0 from any of the configured repositories." error when I try to create a web app. I tried updating the proxies in the settings.xml file but it doesn't seem to be working.  I would really appreciate some help on this one. Thank you

Comment: Please review this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. It would be helpful to post some code and the settings.xml.

Comment: you can refer this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25760961/cannot-create-maven-project-in-eclipse question by Tomer and answer by many experts, it will help you.