# Maven project error in eclipse Java EE

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I Created a Maven project following [this tutorial](http://crunchify.com/how-to-create-dynamic-web-project-using-maven-in-eclipse/), and it worked properly. Now when I create a Maven project again, it gives the following error.

[image: error]

Could anyone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: You'd better paste the error message in plaintext instead of posting an image. This gives searchbots the opportunity to index questions&answers concerning the exact error message. Users namely usually use a search engine like Google to find the answer when using the error message as search query (oh, while we're at it.. have you tried it yourself too?)

Answer (score 0):

I found same error and resolved using this question of StackOverflow

**[solution-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12742467/failed-to-resolve-version-for-org-apache-maven-archetypes/15789286#15789286)** (please follow this link for further assistance)

By following below steps

- Open Window > Preferences
- Open Maven > Archetypes
- Click 'Add Remote Catalog' and add the 
  following:
- Catalog File: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml
- Description: maven catalog

Answer (score 0):

Maven > User Setting > c:\Users\xxxxxxxx.m2\settings.xml

If you are a proxy, you need this configuration:

```
    <proxies>
        <!-- proxy
         | Specification for one proxy, to be used in connecting to the network.
         | -->
          <proxy>
          <id>optional</id>
          <active>true</active>
          <protocol>http</protocol>
          <username>******</username>
          <password>*******</password> 
          <host>*****proxy_host*****</host>
          <port>8080</port>
        </proxy>
   </proxies>
```