# I am not able to create maven Project in STS

Tags: java, spring

I am not able to create maven Project in `STS`. Because when I am selecting any archetype its showing this error.

```
Could not resolve archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:RELEASE from any of the configured repositories.

Could not resolve artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:pom:RELEASE

Failed to resolve version for org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:pom:RELEASE:
Could not find metadata org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\212550433\.m2\repository)

Failed to resolve version for org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:pom:RELEASE:
Could not find metadata org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\212550433\.m2\repository)
```

Comment: Is your question same as this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12742467/failed-to-resolve-version-for-org-apache-maven-archetypes/

Answer (score 0):

execute `mvn clean install` command to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do the following:

- Configure the STS to use an external Maven instance
- Check the external instance works from the command line
- Try to create the maven project again from STS

Comment: I am new to it so Please explain how to configure it ??