# Unable to create maven project

Tags: maven-3

Getting the error can't resolve archtype

[image: error]

I have installed maven in my local and created all environment variables also deleted all folder under .m2/repository folder, but still am getting the error while creating project from eclipse neon.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to resolve version for org.apache.maven.archetypes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12742467/failed-to-resolve-version-for-org-apache-maven-archetypes)

Answer (score 0):

Add the remote catalog into eclipse.

1.Open Window > Preferences

2.Open Maven > Archetypes

3.Click 'Add Remote Catalog' and add the following:

```
Catalog File: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml
Description: maven catalog
```