# Maven doesn't work in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm having some trouble installing Maven on eclipse.

I started following this tutorial:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseMaven/article.html

Last time I did it worked just fine, but this time, when I try to create a maven project it returns me these two errors:

> Could not resolve archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:1.3 from any of the configured repositories.

and

> 'Creating maven-archetype-quickstart' has encountered a problem.
>       Could not resolve archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:1.3 from any configured repositories.

Details for this last error:

> Could not resolve archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:1.3 from any of the configured repositories.
>       Could not resolve artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.3
>       Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.3 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.3 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
>       Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.3 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.3 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty

My network does not have a proxy and linux firewall is disable,

Already tried fixing the catalog like on this topic: [Failed to resolve version for org.apache.maven.archetypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12742467/failed-to-resolve-version-for-org-apache-maven-archetypes/15789286#15789286)  ,

And already tried deleting the repository folder on:`~/.m2/repository`.

I also tried to install maven from the apt repository but I had any idea of how to setup it to work with eclipse.

Any ideas of what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try to build your project outside eclipse?

Comment: you might want to first try maven -U clean install -D skipTests -D gpg.skip on the command line to check that the repository configuration is ok. Making things work in Eclipse as step 2 is IMHO more likely to get you up and running