# couchbase java client 1.2.* fails with maven dependency

Tags: java, maven, couchbase

I'm trying to create a basic java-couchbase hello world application following [this tutorial](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-sdk-java-1.2/).

Added the following dependencies to my pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>couchbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>couchbase-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

But then I get an this error in my pom.xml:

```
ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for
couchbase:couchbase-client:jar:1.2.1: ArtifactResolutionException: 
Failure to transfer couchbase:couchbase-client:pom:1.2.1 from 
http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local 
repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval 
of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could 
not transfer artifact couchbase:couchbase-client:pom:1.2.1 from/to 
central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): null to 
http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/couchbase/couchbase-client/1.2.1/couchbase-client-1.2.1.pom
```

I can see that the jars exist [in maven central distribution](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3a%22com.couchbase.client%22%20AND%20a%3a%22couchbase-client%22), I don't understand why I am getting this error and how can I get over it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did 2 things to resolve this issue:

1. Commented out the proxy section from my maven settings.xml file (following [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5704010/maven-in-5-min-not-working)).
2. Changed my dependency. The old one used maven 2 repo:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>couchbase</groupId>
       <artifactId>couchbase-client</artifactId>
       <version>1.2.3</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

Following [this link](http://www.couchbase.com/communities/java/getting-started), replaced it with:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.couchbase.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>couchbase-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 4):

The exception is pretty straight forward on the error:

```
Failure to transfer couchbase:couchbase-client:pom:1.2.1 from 
http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository
```

Then it says what should be done to fix the issue:

```
resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has 
elapsed or updates are forced.
```

In order to `FORCE` the update use the parameter `-U`

```
 -U,--update-snapshots    Forces a check for updated
                          releases and snapshots on remote
                          repositories
```

From mvn --help option.

Answer (score 0):

Click on your project.

Right click > Team > Synchronize with Repository.

That should sync things up.

If that does not work 
Right click > Run As > Maven Build.  If it pops up a screen that says "goal" past this in "clean install -DskipTests=true".  It's basically saying I want to do an clean installation and you want to skip the tests.

Comment: Team? I'm not working with a source control so I don't see how this relates. Regarding running "clean install -DskipTests=true" - I get Failed to read artifact descriptor for couchbase:couchbase-client:jar:1.2.3: Could not transfer artifact couchbase:couchbase-client:pom:1.2.3 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): null to http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/couchbase/couchbase-client/1.2.3/couchbase-client-1.2.3.pom: UnresolvedAddressException -> [Help 1]