# How to configure proxy for Tomcat on Windows server

Tags: java, tomcat, proxy, tomcat7, windows-server-2008

I have a small webapp running on Windows server 2008 R2 and Tomcat 7.0. Also use the Tomcat service configuration/monitor utility to manage the webapp. 
At the moment the service is behind an http proxy, and need to communicate with a webpage outside. I tried setting `-Dhttp.proxyHost=<server>` and `-Dhttp.proxyPort=<port>` against Java options in the configuration tool.  Also tried setting the flags in `conf/catalina.properties` but still doesn't help.. What could I be doing wrong ? Does it have anything to do with the Windows proxy settings ?

[This problem has been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309800/tomcat-and-proxy-settings) and answered several times, but none of the solutions seem to work for me.

EDIT: I tried all possibilities, Java Configuration, Internet explorer settings and the jvm flags as said in the question. None of them works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay. I think I figured out what was going wrong. I was using Apache httpclient and it has to be configured for proxy separately.

I would expect all external libraries to honor the Java default flags, and pick up user configurations. But it doesn't seem to be the case, unfortunately.

Hope this helps someone.