# URLConnection doesn't use proxy settings

Tags: java, urlconnection, http-proxy

I have a problem with `HttpsURLConnection` - proxy is not used.
Here is the code:

```
//proxy
String type = "https";
System.getProperties().put(type + ".proxyHost", host);
System.getProperties().put(type + ".proxyPort", port);
System.getProperties().put(type + ".proxyUser", username);
System.getProperties().put(type + ".proxyPassword", password);

/*some SSL stuff*/

//connection
URL url = new URL(url0);
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
urlConnection.setDoOutput(false);           
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");   

HttpsURLConnection httpConn = (HttpsURLConnection)urlConnection;
httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
httpConn.setRequestProperty("Proxy-Authorization", "Basic " + Base64Converter.encode(username + ":" + password));
httpConn.connect();
```

All proxy settings are ignored by the connection and `httpConn.usingProxy()` is `false`.
I also tried to pass `Proxy` instance to `url.openConnection()` and setting proxy login/password to default `Authenticator`. The connection used proxy in that case, but I got 407, so it seems that Authenticator doesn't work correctly for me.

Comment: What is the value of url0? Does it actually use https:// ?

Comment: Yes, it is "https://...."

Comment: Are you running the code on Windows - or which o/s does it run on?

Comment: Yes, I run it on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
System.getProperties().put(type + ".proxyUser", username);
System.getProperties().put(type + ".proxyPassword", password);
```

According to [the official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/properties.html), the JRE does not recognized either of these. I believe the Apache HTTP Client may do so, but don't quote me.

You need to install a `java.net.Authenticator.`

Comment: Yep, it seems that I should mess with `Authenticator` to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

From [How do I make HttpURLConnection use a proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432961/how-do-i-make-httpurlconnection-use-a-proxy):

Since java 1.5 you can also pass a java.net.Proxy instance to the openConnection() method:

```
//Proxy instance, proxy ip = 10.0.0.1 with port 8080
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("10.0.0.1", 8080));
conn = new URL(urlString).openConnection(proxy);
```

If your proxy requires authentication it will give you response 407.

In this case you'll need the following code:

```
Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator() {

    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return (new PasswordAuthentication("user",
                "password".toCharArray()));
    }
};
Authenticator.setDefault(authenticator);
```

Comment: I mentioned in my question that there are some problems with that method.