# How to use Http,Socksproxies in java?

Tags: java

my java app needs to connect to the  internet , I am behind a proxy server. i use the fallow 
functions to set proxy but it doesn't work?

```
System.getProperties().put("http.proxySet", "true");
System.getProperties().put("http.socksProxyHost", value);
System.getProperties().put("http.socksProxyPort", value);
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432961/how-do-i-make-httpurlconnection-use-a-proxy), especially the answer which uses [Proxy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Proxy.html) class.

Comment: I use PROXY class as fallows :                                      

Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS,newInetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1",15667));

 url = new URL(siteAddress); 

httpUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(proxy);
but give this error :Malformed reply from SOCKS server and the my  java app stop when url.openConnection(proxy);

Answer (score 0):

Check the system parameter names. There are two ways you can do this:

- Set the system parameter from the command line itself

> ```
> java -Dhttp.proxyHost=proxyhostURL
> -Dhttp.proxyPort=proxyPortNumber
> -Dhttp.proxyUser=userName
> -Dhttp.proxyPassword=password YourProgram
> ```

OR Set these parameter in the code as follows

> System.getProperties().put("http.proxyHost", "proxyURL");
>   System.getProperties().put("http.proxyPort", "proxyPort");
>   System.getProperties().put("http.proxyUser", "userName");
>   System.getProperties().put("http.proxyPassword", "password");