# sending messages from desktop applicationn to web application

Tags: java, web, communication

I'm trying to implement a desktop application that could send http messages to an already open local web application so that it will be updated with this information.

Any suggestions?

The only idea I came up with is sending http requests to the relevant web server and implementing on the web server a servlet that will update the relevant web page according to userID.

Anyone has a more elegant solution?

Comment: You could send the HTTP request with localhost if its a local web application that receives http messages..

Comment: you're supposed to research it first and show us what you tried

Comment: Sorry.. New to this forum ( I mean actually asking questions). You mean I should write code? I work in a security company and my only access to the internet is through my mobile and it will bee quite hard to write code with the android keyboard....

Comment: Cowls, thanks for your comment. I figured I could send messages to localhost. My question is how do I listen to the messages. Is websocket a good approach?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you you want to implement servlet that performs HTTP connection to other, external server. If I am right the following discussion will help you:

[How do I make HttpURLConnection use a proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432961/how-do-i-make-httpurlconnection-use-a-proxy)

Take a look on the answer that explains how to use `Proxy` class introduced in java 1.5.

Comment: Not quite. I want a desktop application (java) to communicate with local web page