# Apache HTTP Client giving 503 Status code instead fo 200

Tags: java, apache, http

I am trying to get the status code for a URL using Apache HTTPGet request. For a URL which belongs to China Marketplace Domain(something like :www.URL.cn) i am getting a return code 503 whereas when i am trying to load the URL in browser i am getting 200 return STatus. Any clues where it might be wrong. Here is the code:

```
    HttpGet urlGet = new HttpGet(URL); // URL being any valid URL
    HttpResponse urlResponse = (HttpResponse) httpClient.execute(urlGet);
    int returnCode = urlResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

I have tried setting User Agent as well but with no success. Is there any additional thing required to resolve this.

Comment: Maybe it is a proxy problem.

Comment: If you ping the server, what happens? Do you have a proxy? Is it https? There are lots of things that can happen, really.

Comment: Yes , its going through a proxy. Is there anyway to bypass proxy.

Comment: Well, you can set a system variable http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432961/how-do-i-make-httpurlconnection-use-a-proxy