# Can the Gmail REST Api be used when you are behing a corporate proxy?

Tags: java, gmail-api

Is it possible to use the Gmail REST API to retrieve emails (with the complete body) when you are behind a corporate HTTP proxy?

If so, can someone please provide a Java example to atleast make the connection using the proxy, so I can figure out the rest by myself?

Ok, so I see that my question has been marked as duplicate, and am given the following link:
[How do I make HttpURLConnection use a proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432961/how-do-i-make-httpurlconnection-use-a-proxy)

This does not help me at all. I am referring to the Gmail REST API (https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/quickstart-java). Have a look at the quickstart link I sent, it doesnt use HttpURLConnection.

It would have been courteous and productive if someone asked me before marking my question as duplicate thereby multiplying my work.

So again I ask, how can I make a connection to the Gmail REST API if I am behind a corporate proxy? In order to avoid confusion, please answer with respect to the example provided in the quickstart link I sent above.

Comment: It looks like that question does answer the question you asked.  Can Gmail REST be accessed behind a firewall.  Yes.  [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1433296/442351) says how to connect to a REST interface.

Comment: Try setting the system properties as described [here](http://i4t.org/2007/05/04/java-http-proxy-settings/). There is a good chance HttpUrlConnection is used behing the scenes or that the Google APIs honor these settings

Answer (score 0):

I have been searching for the same from quite a long time ago and finally I am able to inject the corporate proxy and make successfully connection to Gmail REST API.

Here you go - 
In order to get this done , you need to add below code snippet in https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/quickstart-java

> `static HttpTransport newProxyTransport() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
>           NetHttpTransport.Builder builder = new NetHttpTransport.Builder();
>           builder.trustCertificates(GoogleUtils.getCertificateTrustStore());
>           builder.setProxy(new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("10.0.0.1", 8080)));
>           return builder.build();
>         }`

call the newProxyTransport() in quickStart.java as below :

`static {
        try {
            HTTP_TRANSPORT = newProxyTransport();
            DATA_STORE_FACTORY = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }`

Hope this helps :-)