# Android post request has been truncated

Tags: android, proxy, request, httpurlconnection

I need to upload file to `asp` server from mobile. The function is work until client need add proxy for upload server.

On `iOS` I used `NSMutableURLRequest` and append file to `HttpBody` as data,

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:NSURL(string:urlString)!)
request.HTTPBody = uploader.createBodyWithParameters()
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {...}
```

Which is work,

on `android` I used `HttpUrlConnection`, I found request has been truncated, that all the data send by `OutputStream` is disappear.

```
URL connectURL = new URL(serverURL);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) connectURL.openConnection();

            conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-usa");

            conn.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + uploader.accesstoken);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);


            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\""
                            + fileName +"\"" + lineEnd);

            dos.writeBytes("Content-Type: "+"application/zip, application/octet-stream"+"\r\n\r\n");

            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath+"/"+fileName));
            int bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            int maxBufferSize = 1024 * 1024;

            int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            byte[]buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // read file and write it into form...
            int bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {

                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            }

            // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
```

Here is ios request data

```
POST /Upload.ashx HTTP/1.1
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 6998
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=Boundary-417BEF5E-9840-4369-B397-C5BA87C25D9E
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-usa
Authorization: ...
Host: 192.168.1.5
User-Agent: Apploader/11 CFNetwork/758.2.8 Darwin/15.6.0

--Boundary-417BEF5E-9840-4369-B397-C5BA87C25D9E
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="..."
Content-Type: application/zip, application/octet-stream

.......    
--Boundary-417BEF5E-9840-4369-B397-C5BA87C25D9E--
```

Android end by " User-Agent: Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 6.0.1; SM-G925V Build/MMB29K)"

```
POST /AppLoader/Upload.ashx HTTP/1.1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 7464126
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=Boundary-fc13ac98-53bf-4f3f-9a56-ddc4393d8719
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Authorization: Bearer ..
Host: ...
User-Agent: Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 6.0.1; SM-G925V Build/MMB29K)
```

I am petty sure the problem on happen when proxy has been added, without proxy, the upload function is work.  My question is what is different between iOS and Android make android upload failed, How to fix this?

here is proxy code:

```
using Client.Proxy.Controllers;
using Client.Utilites;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace Proxy.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("Loader")]
    public class AppLoaderController : BaseApiController
    {
        public AppLoaderController()
        {
            base.defaultServiceProxyName = "Loader";
        }
        [HttpPost]
        [ActionName("Upload.ashx")]
        public HttpResponseMessage Upload()
        {
            HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage();
            try
            {
                LoggingUtilities.WriteLog("Upload Started", TraceEventType.Verbose);
                var connector = GetConnectorProxyURI("AppLoaderReceiver").ToString();                 
                LoggingUtilities.WriteLog(string.Format( "Connector: {0}", connector), TraceEventType.Verbose);

                string requestUri = string.Format("{0}/Upload.ashx", connector.Replace("/AppLoader", "/"));
                LoggingUtilities.WriteLog(string.Format("requestUri: {0}", requestUri), TraceEventType.Verbose);

                MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                byte[] buffer = null;
                try
                {
                    HttpPostedFile file;
                    string requestFileName = string.Format("request-{0:yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss-tt}.txt", DateTime.Now);
                    LoggingUtilities.WriteLog(string.Format("log request to file."), TraceEventType.Verbose);
                    HttpContext.Current.Request.SaveAs(string.Format(@"c:\temp\{0}", requestFileName), true);
                    LoggingUtilities.WriteLog(string.Format("About to check Current.Request.Files.Count"), TraceEventType.Verbose);
                    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count > 0)
                    {
                        file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0];
                        LoggingUtilities.WriteLog(string.Format("file.ContentLength ={0}", file.ContentLength), TraceEventType.Verbose);
                        using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream))
                        {
                            buffer = reader.ReadBytes(file.ContentLength);
                        }
                        LoggingUtilities.WriteLog("Got FileData", TraceEventType.Verbose);
                        content.Add(new ByteArrayContent(buffer, 0, buffer.Length), "application/zip", file.FileName);
                        LoggingUtilities.WriteLog("Got ByteArrayContent", TraceEventType.Verbose);
                        string fileName = "";
                        fileName = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0].FileName;
                        LoggingUtilities.WriteLog(string.Format("Filename= {0}", fileName), TraceEventType.Verbose);
                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
                        {
                            TimeSpan span = (TimeSpan)(DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(0x7b1, 1, 1));
                            string str3 = span.TotalMilliseconds.ToString().Substring(0, 13);
                            fileName = string.Format("*.zip", str3);
                        }
                        content.Add(new StringContent(fileName), "FILE_NAME");
                        Task<HttpResponseMessage> task1 = new HttpClient().PostAsync(requestUri, content);
                        task1.Wait();
                        result = task1.Result;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception2)
            {
                result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[How do I make HttpURLConnection use a proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432961/how-do-i-make-httpurlconnection-use-a-proxy) this answer may help you ;
In android there are many http tools, like volley ,aysnchttp,okhttp... you can choose one of them to instead of original HttpUrlConnection;
we may know more about this issue if you can add log print in code and give us the log;

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Chris and Gao.
I fixed this question by remove

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
```

Which effect server convert text message to gzip before it was sending to android.

Another problem come from when I got -1 from conn.getContentLength(), 
I thought the content is empty, but it is only means request have a unknown content length.  still could read content from conn.getInputStream().