# How to use auth-required proxy for Http request in Android app?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, authentication, http-proxy

I am sending a post request with following code.

```
    Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(proxyAddr, proxyPort));
    URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection(proxy);
    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
    ...
```

Here I can set the proxy server address and port. But I wonder how I can add proxy username and password here.

I read some posts about calling http request via proxy but no one was talking about proxy authentication.

Hope some help from you guys.

---

### PS:

Some people suggest using this code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432961/how-do-i-make-httpurlconnection-use-a-proxy)

```
Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator() {

    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return (new PasswordAuthentication("user",
                "password".toCharArray()));
    }
};
Authenticator.setDefault(authenticator);
```

but this is not working at all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make HttpURLConnection use a proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432961/how-do-i-make-httpurlconnection-use-a-proxy)

Comment: @EdGeorge, I already checked that post and it doesn't work.

Comment: Please be more specific: it doesn't work how? What error do you get?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel It says "Authentication failture"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I figured it out.

Added Authorization Header to the request.

```
String credential = Credentials.basic(proxyUsername, proxyPassword);
urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Proxy-Authorization", credential);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer and works very well.  Don't use Authenticator with Android as it doesn't work. Thanks for figuring it out for us.