# How to send a file to proxy server in Java

Tags: java, http, https, proxy

Have a server https://abcxx.com and need to upload a file to this at location https://abcxx.com/internalfolder/ . Have obtained a proxy for the server with a proxy host and proxy port. How to connect to this proxy and send the file to the required folder? Tried few examples but not much success.

```
URL weburl = new URL("https://abcxx.com");
        Proxy socksProxy 
          = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("proxyhost", proxyport));
        HttpURLConnection socksConnection 
          = (HttpURLConnection) weburl.openConnection(socksProxy);
```

Iam new to networking so im not sure if iam doing this right in above sample code.

Comment: Are you using any library for doing connection? like Apache httpclient.

Comment: Only libraries im using are mentioned in above code snippet:        

import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Proxy;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.URL;

Comment: Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432961/how-do-i-make-httpurlconnection-use-a-proxy. It has different options to use proxy.

Comment: In the given link, in the code there is urlstring, which url should i use here? The actual server url in my case  https://abcxx.com or the intended folder https://abcxx.com/internalfolder/

Comment: The url should be the intended folder. Else it will try to upload at abcxx.com but you want the file to be uploaded at abcxx.com/internalfolder.

Comment: I tried this 
````Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("proxyhost", proxyport));
conn = new URL("https://abcxx.com/internalfolder/").openConnection(proxy);````

And 403 is the response

Comment: Does your proxy have authentication required? username/password. If yes then please configure it samples in that given link. If not required then please check your API it seems you don't have permission to upload.

Answer (score 0):

```
jschSession = jsch.getSession("username", "abcxx.com", 22);
    jschSession.setProxy(new ProxyHTTP(proxyhost:proxyport));

    // authenticate using password
    jschSession.setPassword(password));
    java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
    config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    jschSession.setConfig(config);

    // 10 seconds session timeout
    jschSession.connect(10000);

    Channel sftp = jschSession.openChannel("sftp");

    // 5 seconds timeout
    sftp.connect(5000);
```

This solved my issue