# Emacs behind HTTP proxy

Tags: emacs, proxy, elpa

Emacs is able to access the Internet with packages such as [url.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/UrlPackage) or the [W3 web browser](http://www.gnu.org/software/w3/).

Also, the [Emacs Lisp Package Archive](http://tromey.com/elpa/) is heavily dependent on package url.el.

Now, how do I configure Emacs to use my HTTP proxy to connect to the Internet in general?

Bonus points for any help with ELPA behind a proxy.

Yes, [I've had problems with HTTP proxies before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120797/how-do-i-set-the-proxy-to-be-used-by-the-jvm).

Answer (score 56, accepted):

For w3m, this setting has worked for me:

```
(setq url-proxy-services '(("no_proxy" . "work\\.com")
                           ("http" . "proxy.work.com:911")))
```

Comment: @Trey Jackson: What if the proxy requires authentication?

Comment: If you require authentication, Emacs (at least 23.x) will ask you for your username and password, provided you have url-proxy-services set.

Comment: Is it possible to make Emacs use IE proxy settings?

Comment: @gm There's no package that I know of that does it.

Comment: @grm - see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10050186/is-it-possible-to-tell-emacs-on-windows-to-use-the-ie-http-proxy-settings/10050208#10050208

Comment: Just confirmed Emacs 22 will prompt for credentials as well. Thank you  @MikeHoss

Comment: I had to add another line identical to the "http" line for https, but otherwise this did the trick for me.

Answer (score 27):

I've got authorization working by:

```
(setq url-proxy-services
   '(("no_proxy" . "^\\(localhost\\|10\\..*\\|192\\.168\\..*\\)")
     ("http" . "proxy.com:8080")
     ("https" . "proxy.com:8080")))

(setq url-http-proxy-basic-auth-storage
    (list (list "proxy.com:8080"
                (cons "Input your LDAP UID !"
                      (base64-encode-string "LOGIN:PASSWORD")))))
```

Works for Emacs 24.3. It is based on non-public API tricks, so might not work in another Emacs versions...

Comment: legend! btw this did not work for emacs 26 on windows, but was fine for 25.3

Comment: this worked for me (emacs 25.1.1 mingw from the gnu mirrors).   If you're still playing SO -- I believe you want "10\..*" for the local host, you'll match anything that  starts 10 with what you got there.

Comment: @LevinMagruder Updated!

Answer (score 14):

Emacs populates the `url-proxy-services` variable from the [`http_proxy`, `https_proxy` and `no_proxy` environment variables](http://kaamka.blogspot.ca/2009/06/httpproxy-environment-variable.html) if they are set.

Comment: This is totally the way to go

Comment: Yes well, it doesn't work in my environment.  I think they have some Bluecoat ssl cert also.  How is that dealt with?

Answer (score 5):

This is a bit old, but I had issues connecting as well. One thing I needed to do is add my certificate to the the `gnutls-trustfiles` in order to connect.

```lisp
(with-eval-after-load 'gnutls
    (add-to-list 'gnutls-trustfiles "path/to/cert.crt"))
(setq url-proxy-services
   '(("no_proxy" . "^\\(localhost\\|10\\..*\\|192\\.168\\..*\\)")
     ("http" . "proxy.com:8080")
     ("https" . "proxy.com:8080")))
```