# Some tweaks to enable Clojure development on Aquamacs

Tags: clojure, aquamacs

I'm trying to enable Clojure development on Aquamacs.  I followed this article:  http://mischneider.net/?p=171
When I tried to run (alt+x) slime, Aquamacs asked me if I want to download Clojure and then it tried to download Clojure 1.1.0 , but it got the error:
"Unable to download Clojure jars"

Any way I have the Clojure jar, where I have to put it by hand? should I configure something?
Even better, instead of Clojure 1.1 , can I use Clojure 1.2?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use 1.2 and you should. I found setting up Clojure with Emacs easy with [these](http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/clojure/Getting_Started_with_Emacs) instructions. I use [Cocoa Emacs](http://emacsformacosx.com/), but it should work with Aquamacs as well.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you have a problem because of your **proxy** server configuration. Try to set `http_proxy` environment variable or [setup it directly from Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595418/emacs-behind-http-proxy). If this doesn't help, check your steps with [this](http://kids-for-food.blogspot.com/2010/12/emacs-clojure-in-60-seconds.html) tutorial.

You can also use **custom version of Clojure** with [Leiningen](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/)'s `project.clj` configuration file.