# Is it possible to tell emacs on Windows to use the IE http proxy settings?

Tags: emacs, elisp, http-proxy

> See also: [Emacs behind HTTP proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595418/emacs-behind-http-proxy)

Is it possible to tell emacs to *automatically* use whatever proxy settings are in use by IE?

The url.el package says I can explicitly specify a proxy like this:

```
(setq url-using-proxy t)
(setq url-proxy-services  '(("http" . "proxyserver:3128")))
```

Is it possible for this to happen sort of auto-magically, when I change the IE proxy settings?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

The basic idea is to define before-advice for the URL functions, and set those variables to appropriate values. This requires being able to retrieve the IE proxy settings from Windows, from within elisp.

The [w32-registry package](http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/w32-registry) does this.

Therefore, on Windows, you can do this:

```
(eval-after-load "url"
  '(progn
     (require 'w32-registry)
     (defadvice url-retrieve (before
                              w32-set-proxy-dynamically
                              activate)
       "Before retrieving a URL, query the IE Proxy settings, and use them."
       (let ((proxy (w32reg-get-ie-proxy-config)))
         (setq url-using-proxy proxy
               url-proxy-services proxy)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are handling URL's via browse-url, you can also set it to Windows-specific function like this.  Then the URL's will be handled by Windows (invoking your default browser).

> browse-url-browser-function is a variable defined in `browse-url.el'.
>
> Its value is browse-url-default-windows-browser