# Automatic proxy auth for Emacs 23.1

Tags: authentication, emacs, proxy

This answer for Emacs 24 does not seem to work for 23:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18697151/2022518

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to recall there being a bug in the proxy auth support until a year or two ago.  23.1 is from 2009, probably its about time to upgrade?

Comment: I wish I could.. I'm stuck on RH 6.3 for non-technical reasons.