# How to add proxy support to Jsoup?

Tags: java, jsoup

I am a beginner to Java and my first task is to parse some 10,000 URLs and extract some info out of it, for this I am using **Jsoup** and it's working fine.

But now I want to add proxy support to it. The proxies have a username and password too.

Comment: Hmm, have you tried using HtmlUnit instead? That should be up to the task

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120797/how-do-i-set-the-proxy-to-be-used-by-the-jvm

Comment: yah i have used but i still think that jsoup works better for my requirement. All i m confused is how to work efficiently with proxies using jsoup.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You don't have to get the webpage data through Jsoup. Here's my solution, it may not be the best though.

```
  URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com/");
  Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 8080)); // or whatever your proxy is
  HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection(proxy);

  uc.connect();

    String line = null;
    StringBuffer tmp = new StringBuffer();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream()));
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
      tmp.append(line);
    }

    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(String.valueOf(tmp));
```

And there it is. This gets the source of the html page through a proxy and then parses it with Jsoup.

Comment: good solution. is there any way i can use NIO based fecthing atfter uc.connect?

Comment: For the casual reader, it's possible to pass Jsoup the inputstream of the HttpURLConnection directly. See the following answer for details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42085445/363573

Comment: well can you use cookies using such method for example to download page which needs login pass? I think Jsoup should be always used

Answer (score 70):

You can easily set proxy

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "192.168.5.1");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "1080");
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("www.google.com").get();
```

Comment: and don't forget to set to null after the call otherwise the other calls that don't need it will be very slow

Comment: If you use [code]Jsoup.connect("www.google.com").get() now, it gives a MalformedURLException.

Comment: I couldnt seem to get this setting to work.  Jsoup.connect would successfully complete regardless of the IP i set the proxyHost to.

Comment: @jln646v The following answer describes how to setup Jsoup with a proxy: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34943161/363573.

Comment: I agree with @jln646v.  Better to use `Jsoup.proxy(proxy)`.

Comment: This is the only solution if you need to connect to https. Just change "http" with "https". +1. Proxy class doesn't support Proxy.Type.HTTPS, so all answers that suggest that way aren't feasible if you need to connect to https.

Answer (score 54):

**Jsoup 1.9.1 and above: (recommended approach)**

```
// Fetch url with proxy
Document doc = Jsoup //
               .connect("http://www.example.com/") //
               .proxy("127.0.0.1", 8080) // sets a HTTP proxy
               .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.4; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2") //
               .header("Content-Language", "en-US") //
               .get();
```

You may use also the overload [Jsoup#proxy](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html#proxy-java.net.Proxy-) which takes a [Proxy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Proxy.html?is-external=true) class (see below).

**Before Jsoup 1.9.1: (verbose approach)**

```
// Setup proxy
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(                                      //
        Proxy.Type.HTTP,                                      //
        InetSocketAddress.createUnresolved("127.0.0.1", 8080) //
);

// Fetch url with proxy
Document doc = Jsoup //
               .connect("http://www.example.com/") //
               .proxy(proxy) //
               .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.4; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2") //
               .header("Content-Language", "en-US") //
               .get();
```

**References:**

- [Connection#proxy(String,int)](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html#proxy-java.lang.String-int-)
- [Connection#proxy(Proxy)](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html#proxy-java.net.Proxy-)
- [Proxy class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Proxy.html?is-external=true)

Comment: Hi,I'm using JSoup 1.9.1 - I tried both the approaches mentioned in the answer but to no results. I'm working under a proxy, but I can access the url mentioned in connect method. I'm getting the same error everytime - `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect`

Comment: I tried the approach mentioned by Alex too https://stackoverflow.com/a/27819164/4941819
It didn't help either.

Comment: @NakulSharma The error `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect` may indicate that the target host doesn't listen or refuses some clients connections.

Answer (score 6):

You might like to add this before running the program

```
final String authUser = "USERNAME";
final String authPassword = "PASSWORD";



Authenticator.setDefault(
               new Authenticator() {
                  public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                     return new PasswordAuthentication(
                           authUser, authPassword.toCharArray());
                  }
               }
            );

..

System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "192.168.5.1");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "1080");
..
```

Answer (score 5):

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "192.168.5.1");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "1080");
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("www.google.com").get();
```

This is wrong solution, because parsing is usually multithreaded and we usually need to change proxies. This code sets only one proxy for all threads. So better to not use Jsoup.Connection.

Comment: For using Jsoup.Connection, see the following answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/34943161/363573

Answer (score 3):

**Jsoup does support using proxies**, since [v1.9.1](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/blob/master/CHANGES). [`Connection` class](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html) has the following methods:

- `proxy(Proxy p)`
- `proxy(String host, int port)`

Which you can use it like this:

```
Jsoup.connect("...url...").proxy("127.0.0.1", 8080);
```

If you need authentication, you can use the `Authenticator` approach mentioned by [@Navneet Swaminathan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28522424/2418224) or simply set [system properties](https://www.javacodeexamples.com/set-jsoup-proxy-in-java-example/773):

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyUser", "username");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPassword", "password");
```

or

```
System.setProperty("https.proxyUser", "username");
System.setProperty("https.proxyPassword", "password");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code instead:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com/");
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 8080)); // or whatever your proxy is

HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection(proxy);
hc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.4; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2");
uc.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
uc.setRequestMethod("GET");
uc.connect();

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(uc.getInputStream());
```