# POST Password and Email data to Google Sign-in

Tags: java, android, jsoup

All- I have the code:

```
doc = Jsoup.connect("https://play.google.com/apps/publish/Home?dev_acc=00758402038897917238")
                      .data("input#Email", "email@gmail.com")
                      .data("input#Passwd", "123abcABC123" )
                      .post();
```

I got his from here: [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10012399/how-to-post-data-into-website-using-jsoup) but could not figure out what is wrong. I am getting the sign in page instead of the page displaying all my published apps. I belive the problem might lie in the `input#Email` and `input#Passwd` but I am not sure. I don't quite understand what that is supposed to refer to. So my question: **how can I login to my developer console using code similar to the one above and what is supposed to go where `input#Email` and `input#Passwd` are?**

Comment: maybe it would be more appropriate to get an auth_token from the device instead of sending passwords in plain text?

Answer (score 0):

In post you have to use names, not css selectors:

```
doc = Jsoup.connect("https://play.google.com/apps/publish/Home?dev_acc=00758402038897917238")
                      .data("Email", "email@gmail.com")
                      .data("Passwd", "123abcABC123" )
                      .post();
```